# Issue with extension method

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace LambdaExtensionEx
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] myStrngs = new string[] { "Super","Simple","Okay"};
            IEnumerable<string> criteraStrngs = myStrngs.WhereSearch<string>(delegate(string s)
            {
                return s.StartsWith("s");
            });

            string s1 = "dotnet";
            int count = s1.GetCount();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class MyExtension
    {
        public delegate bool Criteria<T>(T Value);

        public static IEnumerable<T> WhereSearch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, Criteria<T> critera)
        {
            foreach (T value in values)
                if (critera(value))
                    yield return value;
        }

        public static int GetCount(this string value)
        {
            return value.Count();
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to call GetCount extension method and I get result in 'count'. But WhereSearch is not being called in any time and not getting result. What mistake am I doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to start enumerating over the result returned by the `WhereSearch` function if you want it to get executed. The reason for that is because this function `yield returns` an `IEnumerable<T>`. What the C# compiler does is build a state machine and doesn't execute the function immediately until the calling code starts enumerating over the result.

For example:

```
// The function is not executed at this stage because this function uses 
// yield return to build an IEnumerable<T>
IEnumerable<string> criteraStrngs = myStrngs.WhereSearch<string>(delegate(string s)
{
    return s.StartsWith("s");
});
// Here we start enumerating over the result => the code will start executing
// the function.
foreach (var item in criteraStrngs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Another example is calling some of the LINQ extension methods such as `.ToList()` on the result which will actually enumerate and call the function:

```
IEnumerable<string> criteraStrngs = myStrngs.WhereSearch<string>(delegate(string s)
{
    return s.StartsWith("s");
})
.ToList();
```

For more details on how lazy loading works in this case you may take a look at the [`following post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756958/how-yield-implements-the-pattern-of-lazy-loading).

Answer (score 0):

Your extension methods class doesn't make much sense -  why don't you just do this?

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] myStrngs = new string[] { "Super", "Simple", "Okay" };
        IEnumerable<string> criteraStrngs = myStrngs.Where(x => x.StartsWith("s"));

        string s1 = "dotnet";
        int count = s1.Count();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

As stated by Darin Dimitrov previously - you will still need to enumerate criteriaStrngs to get a result out of it - which is what was wrong with your original code.

HTH

Comment: I tried to implement extension method on my own. I know that Where is there. Thanks for the reply