# Can I use ES6's arrow function syntax with generators? (arrow notation)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, syntax, generator, arrow-functions

That is, how do I express

```
function *(next) {}
```

with arrow syntax? I've tried all the combinations I could think of, and I can't find any documentation on it.

(I am currently using Node.js v0.11.14.)

Comment: You can't. Sorry. "The `function*` statement (function keyword followed by an asterisk) defines a generator function."

Comment: https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/c61f48cea5f2339a1ec65ca89827c8cff170779b/es6/2013-11/nov-20.md#410-generator-arrow-function-syntax

Comment: Note that there was a somewhat-lengthy discussion on this topic [at esdiscuss.org](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/generator-arrow-functions).

Comment: What is the purpose of the parentheses around `next`? I think this is invalid syntax.

Comment: `next` is just an argument being passed into the function, isn't it? Admitedly it isn't needed for the example ...

Comment: What do you expect `param*=>{   }` to do?

Comment: @CodeiSir to provide an in-line generator function.

Comment: you know that `function(){}` is not doing the same as `()=>{}` ?

Comment: @CodeiSir, how is this relevant?

Comment: "*is it really that ES6 generators are 2 steps forward and 1 step back?*" - no, [generators can only step forward](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23848531/1048572) :-)

Comment: @vitaly-t: It's relevant as far as [arrow functions are not just a syntactic replacement for bound function expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32535110/1048572), and that you cannot expect the same syntax to work for other functions.

Comment: @Bergi the link to the "doublicate" does not contain an explanation. Should I move my answer to the other post?

Comment: @Bergi I think it does explain it: "As a consequence, arrow functions cannot be used as generators."

Comment: @CodeiSir: But why is that so? The spec could pretty trivially have allowed us to use a syntax like `(param) =*> { yield param; }` (or whatever). Your answer doesn't give the reason why that was not done.

Comment: well I then state "Why Arrow-function can not use yield" wich together explains why it can not be done

Comment: *()={} would be the consistent path for what yo are asking in ES6...
but I think it is not available yet...

Comment: I really don't understand the generator designator asterisk. Why not make any function containing a yield statement a generator function like Python?

Comment: I really wish they would have just used 'generator' as a keyword in place of function. The asterisk feels so random.

Answer (score 356, accepted):

> Can I use ES6's arrow function syntax with generators?

You can't. Sorry.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

> The `function*` statement (`function` keyword followed by an asterisk) defines a generator function.

From a [spec document](https://web.archive.org/web/20170126155949/http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:generators) (my emphasis):

> The **function** syntax is extended to add an optional `*` token:

```
FunctionDeclaration: "function" "*"? Identifier "(" FormalParameterList? ")" 
  "{" FunctionBody "}"
```

Comment: Feels like a design flaw to me.

Comment: @Jonathon: No. Arrow functions are supposed to be light-weight (and don't have a `.prototype` for example) and often one-liners, while generators are pretty much the opposite.

Comment: I have already run across a few scenarios where a generator I was playing with needed access to the previous `this`, and had to write the `let self = this` hack to get access to it inside the generator. The lexical scope + arrow syntax would have been nice. Unfortunate, but not exactly the end of the world.

Comment: @Bergi: Do you have any idea of whether they're handled differently under the surface? Things may have changed but last time I checked arrow functions were just normal functions automatically wrapped in `bind()`.

Comment: @Jonathon: I don't think they ever were. They might be transpiled to `.bind`, but that's not how they are specced in ES6.

Comment: Some additional context around this at [esdiscuss](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/generator-arrow-functions)

Comment: @Bergi the reasoning behind arrow functions is a lot more complicated than that. It's not really about brevity. Arrow functions needn't be lightweight – it's true there's an optional single-statement body syntax, but so what. Many people use arrows for all function definitions except class methods, and demote the `function` keyword to being a 'bad part' of the language. There are good reasons to do this. For these people, the lack of arrow generators is an annoying inconsistency.

Comment: @callum I did mean lightweight in terms of instance creation and call overhead, not syntax. Not sure what you think the reasoning behind them was. And no, I don't see any good reasons to use non-declarative arrow function expressions over `function` declarations.

Comment: @callum Agreed. I always try to stick with `class` for creating objects and arrow functions as first-class lambdas (e.g. argument to a method), in addition to methods (instance and static) as needed. Sticking with these, I haven't found a compelling reason to continue using the `function` keyword. Other than where it’s required, of course, such as in a framework.

Comment: To me, not having generator arrow functions is as bad as not having async arrow functions.

Answer (score 166):

### The difference between Inline-functions and Arrow-functions

First of all [Arrow-functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `() => {}` are not made to replace Inline-functions `function(){}` and they are different.
Inline-Functions are simply Functions, so the question is what the difference between Arrow-functions and Inline-Functions are.

> An arrow function expression (also known as arrow function) has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and does not bind its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`). Arrow functions are always anonymous.

Some more quick details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535110/what-are-the-differences-if-any-between-es6-arrow-functions-and-functions-boun)

---

### Why Arrow-function can not be used as generators

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Use_of_the_yield_keyword)

> **Use of the yield keyword**
>
> The [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) keyword may not be used in an arrow function's body (except when permitted within functions further nested within it).  As a consequence, arrow functions cannot be used as generators.

Note that [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) without `yield` don't make sense.

---

### Why Arrow-function can not use yield

http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/arrow-functions/

> Arrow functions bind `this` lexically, bind `return` in the *Block* body case so it returns from the immediately enclosing arrow function, and preclude `break` and `continue` from referencing statements outside the immediately enclosing arrow function.
>
> The *Identifier* primary expression `arguments` may not be used in an arrow function's body (whether expression or block form).
>
> Likewise, `yield` may not be used in an arrow function's body. Arrows cannot be generators and we do not want deep continuations.

Yield in an Arrow-Function will throw Semantic Error: [http://www.ecma-international.org/](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors)

In the End the reason is in the deep complexity in the implementation of ECMA6. C# does not allow this as well for somewhat similar [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862621/why-can-you-not-use-yield-in-a-lambda-when-you-can-use-await-in-a-lambda).

Comment: Would you please elaborate on why that is, and/or include explanation of why that `()=>{}` comparison is relevant? Because I don't understand yet why this limitation.

Comment: I used a search engine and posted one more Explanation for you

Comment: I still think that adding explanation about `()=>{}` would help a lot, to understand its difference from an in-line function, and why the limitation is there for generators.

Comment: An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target). Arrow functions are always anonymous.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why `*() => { yield bla; }` isn't ok, but `async () => { await bla; }` is...

Comment: @CodeiSir,  Re "*and we do not want deep continuations*", lousy excuses.

Comment: TC39 often make bad decisions like this

Comment: Your argument is cyclical. You say that arrow functions can't be generators because they can't have the yield keyword in them. But they can't have the yield keyword, because they can't be generators: "Arrows cannot be generators and we do not want deep continuations."

Comment: you don't answer why. Just said that they can't, but why?

Comment: That's circular reasoning; An arrow function can't be a generator, because it's not allowed to have a `yield` statement, and it can't have a `yield` statement, because it's not allowed to be a generator. 

Comment: This doesn’t really answer *why*. Yes it's true, an arrow function can't be a generator because it isn't allowed to contain `yield`, but there's no reason why the syntax could have been designed to allow it. What is the reason the designers didn't want arrow functions to be able to be generators?

Comment: @chharvey feel free to do some additional research, I would be interesting to see how deep the decision making was. And thanks for the downvote, you are welcome :D

Comment: Saying "arrow functions bind `this` lexically" is kind of misleading: rather, they do not implicitly _introduce_ a local `this` like non-arrow functions do. As a result, any reference to `this` binds to the one introduced by the innermost enclosing non-arrow function scope, exactly the same as how any reference to `x` binds to the variable with that name from the innermost scope that introduces one.

Comment: @LeeBenson Exactly - `async` functions are kind of subset of generators that generate Promises, you can see such transformation in [Babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator)

Answer (score 62):

In addition to the discussion on [esdiscuss.org](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/generator-arrow-functions) and [the Ecma TC39 committee ES6 meeting notes from November 2013](https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/42c441d20abfdb1d29760b9ab3cbb005b5620dd2/es6/2013-11/nov-20.md#410-generator-arrow-function-syntax) mentioned above, generator arrows were revisited in two September 2016 ES7 meetings [[1]](https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/42c441d20abfdb1d29760b9ab3cbb005b5620dd2/es7/2016-09/sept-27.md#11ic-generator-arrow-functions) [[2]](https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/42c441d20abfdb1d29760b9ab3cbb005b5620dd2/es7/2016-09/sept-29.md#arrow-generator-revisit). After a discussion about pros and cons of various syntax (mainly `=*>` and `=>*`) and a lack of justifications and use cases for this feature, they came to the conclusion that:

> - There is some interest from the committee, but concern that the feature does not pull its weight for adding a new piece of syntax
> - Plan to revisit on Day 3 to see if we can get `=>*` to stage 0 at least, as part of [Domenic Denicola]'s async iteration proposal

The proposal for generator arrows was moved to [Stage 1](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/stage-1-proposals.md) with Brendan Eich and Domenic Denicola as champions. [Asynchronous iteration](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration) mentioned above was [finished and implemented](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md) in 2018.

In Oct 2019 [an official repo by Sergey Rubanov](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-generator-arrow-functions) appeared with more discussion about syntax and other details.

Comment: "with Brendan Eich ..." He's still fighting to make the language better *decades* after he created the entire thing: hats off to that man!

Answer (score 12):

I was also having the same question and came here. After reading the posts and comments, I felt using generator in an arrow function seems to be vague:

```
const generator = () => 2*3; // * implies multiplication
// so, this would be a confusing
const generator = () =>* something; // err, multiplying?
const generator = () =*> ... // err, ^^
const generator = ()*=> ... // err, *=3, still multiplying?
const generator=*()=> ... // err, ^^
const generator = *param => ... //err, "param" is not fixed word
```

This is what may be the big reason they didn't implement generator in relation with arrow function.

---

But, if I were one of them, I could have thought like this:

```
const generator = gen param => ... // hmm, gen indicates a generator
const generator = gen () => ... // ^^
```

This feels just like we have asynchronous function:

```
const asyncFunction = async () => ... // pretty cool
```

Because, with normal function the **async** keyword exist, so arrow function is utilizing it - `async () =>` is likely to seem `async function()`.

But, there's no keyword like `gen` or `generator` and alas arrow function is not using it.

To conclude:

Even if they wish to implement the generator in the arrow function, I think they need to re-think about generator syntax in core js:

```
generator function myfunc() {}
// rather than
function* myfunc() {} // or, function *myfunc() {}
```

And this will be a big blunder. So, keeping arrow function out from the generator, is pretty cool.

---

Following [@Bergi comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661306/can-i-use-es6s-arrow-function-syntax-with-generators-arrow-notation/54482949#comment47536781_27661420):

> No. Arrow functions are supposed to be light-weight (and don't have a .prototype for example) and often one-liners, while generators are pretty much the opposite.

I will say that generator purpose to use is **run-stop-run** and so I don't think we need to care about prototype, lexical this, etc.

Comment: Could also consider exotic options as well, like `() ~> { yield 'a'; yield 'b'; }`. To be honest I just love tildes.

Comment: @Gershom This is how programming languages like [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) go totally wrong

Comment: I find the solution `const someGeneratorFunction = gen () => ...` quite pretty.

Comment: I think the most mnemonic syntax would be `=>=>`, because a normal function produces one value so it's arguments `=>` [logic to get the return value], while a generator produces potentially multiple values, and because a generator goes, stops, then goes again.

Answer (score 10):

Right now you can not, but in future you might be because TC39 release [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-generator-arrow-functions) for same in october 2019, which is in stage 1.

Answer (score 6):

You can, but not really in a nice way. It's not shorter and does not look that pretty. Check this out:

```js
function* iterable(arg) {
    yield* [];
}

async function* asyncIterable(arg) {
    yield* [];
}

const arrowIterable = arg => {
    return {
        *[Symbol.iterator]() {
            yield* [];
        },
    };
};

const arrowAsyncIterable = arg => {
    return {
        async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
            yield* [];
        },
    };
};
```

This works because an iterable is basically an object with the `Symbol.iterator` or `Symbol.asyncIterator` set to an iterator. A generator is an iterator!

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is very late, but another possible reason could be syntax. maybe `(*() => {})` works, but what about `(9 ** () => {})`? Is that 9 to the power of an arrow function, returning `NaN`, or is it 9 times a generator arrow function, also returning `NaN`? It could be done with some alternative syntax, like `=>*` as mentioned by another answer here, but maybe there was a desire to preserve the consistency of the generator function syntax (eg. `function* () {}` and `{ *genMethod() {} }`) when it was being implemented. Not too much of an excuse, but a reason for it.

Comment: :+1: for the double asterisks... Old school JS guy here. Who says you can't teach an old dog new tricks :joy:

Comment: The only reason they don't do it, is because making the parser is difficult. It's entirely possible and requires no compromise in syntax.

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell If they cared enough about not making parser too complex, then maybe Brendan Eich should have put Scheme in the browser.

Answer (score -7):

There is a nice workaround with redux-saga

```
import { call, all } from 'redux-saga/effects';

function* gen() {
   yield all([].map(() => {
      return call(....);
   }));
}
```

Comment: How do we know OP is using Redux?