# Declare anonymous generator function using arrow syntax

Tags: javascript, lambda, generator, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Is it possible to declare an anonymous generator function using the arrow syntax in ES6 JavaScript?  This is what I've tried:

```
let func = *() => { };
```

but this doesn't parse (I'm using [Babel.js](http://babeljs.io/) to compile my ES6 to ES5).  [The documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) only mentions the more standard syntax:

```
let func = function *() { };
```

I'd like to be able to define the generator function using a arrow in order to take advantage of the lexical scoping of `this`.  Is this possible?

Comment: You can't use fat-arrows for generators. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661306/can-i-use-es6s-fat-arrow-notation-with-generators-node. BTW, it's more common to refer to these as "fat-arrow functions" than "lambdas".

Comment: Your terminology is odd. `function*() {}` is a "lambda" as well (in the form of a function expression).

Comment: What are you trying to do that would necessitate a lexically-scoped `this` in a generator function?

Comment: Thanks @Bergi - I've edited the question to use "fat arrow" instead of "lambda".  I'm converting a standard self-executing function into a self-executing generator function, and I'll need to access class properties inside the generator function.  I think I've found a way to get the same effect using `.apply()`:    `yield* (function *() { }).apply(this)`

Comment: Why would one ever immediately-execute a generator function? If you are going for ES6, use blocks to scope variables. `{ let …; yield…;}`, not `yield* …`.

Comment: Normally, you wouldn't.  In my case, I'm writing a [Cool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_(programming_language)) to JavaScript compiler.  In Cool, *all* expressions return a value, so I use self-executing functions to wrap expressions that don't return a value naturally in JavaScript (i.e. if/then/else expressions).  Also, Cool allows for synchronous user input, which I'm achieving using generators.  So not at all your normal use case.