# What are the differences (if any) between ES6 arrow functions and functions bound with Function.prototype.bind?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, function-binding

It seems to me that, in ES6, the following two functions are very *nearly* identical:

```
function () {
  return this;
}.bind(this);

() => {
  return this;
};
```

The end result seems the same: arrow functions produce a JavaScript function object with their `this` context bound to the same value as the `this` where they are created.

Obviously, in the general sense, `Function.prototype.bind` is more flexible than arrow functions: it can bind to values other than the local `this`, and it can bind any function's `this` at any point in time, potentially long after it is initially created. However, I'm not asking how `bind` itself is different from arrow functions, I'm asking how arrow functions differ from immediately calling `bind` with `this`.

Are there any differences between the two constructs in ES6?

Comment: With `bind` you are essentially creating two functions. Other than that, the things you mentioned and the fact that arrow functions have a  more concise syntax, there is no difference.

Comment: As this question doesn't seek and it's answers do not offer any times where you might have good reason to use `bind` over an arrow function, I have asked a new question about when to do so: https://runkit.com/embed/yhv29j5sybvn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Comment: In the `bind` version it returns a new function which partially applies the arguments to `bind `. Arrow doesn't have `this` so use of it is as any free variable from a higher scope.

Answer (score 40):

## There are no (significant) differences.

Well, okay, that's a little premature. There are three *tiny* differences unique to arrow functions.

1. Arrow functions cannot be used with `new`.

   This means, of course, that they do not have a `prototype` property and cannot be used to create an object with the classically-inspired syntax.

   ```
   new (() => {}) // TypeError: () => {} is not a constructor
   ```

   This is probably for the best, though—the way `new` works would not make much sense with bound functions.
2. Arrow functions do not have access to the special `arguments` object that ordinary JavaScript functions have access to.

   ```
   (() => arguments)(1, 2, 3) // ReferenceError: arguments is not defined
   ```

   This one is probably a little bit more of a gotcha. Presumably this is to remove one of JavaScript's other oddities. [The `arguments` object is its own special beast](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), and it has strange behavior, so it's not surprising that it was tossed.

   Instead, ES6 has splats that can accomplish the same thing without any magic hidden variables:

   ```
   ((...args) => args)(1, 2, 3) // [1, 2, 3]
   ```
3. Arrow functions do not have their own [`new.target`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32450516/465378) property, they use the `new.target` of their enclosing function, if it exists.

   This is consistent with the other changes to remove "magically" introduced values for arrow functions. This particular change is especially obvious, considering arrow functions can't be used with `new` anyway, as mentioned above.

Otherwise, arrows are just like bound functions, semantically. It's possible for arrows to be more performant, since they don't have to carry around the extra baggage and since they don't need to be converted from ordinary functions first, but they're behaviorally exactly the same.

Comment: I wouldn't say `arguments` was tossed because of "strange behavior" (which is fixed in strict mode anyway). Rather, arrow functions can access their enclosing function's `arguments` object, consistent with how they access its `this` binding and `new.target`.

Comment: @Bergi Even in strict mode, `arguments` is considerably strange: it still isn't an array, so a splat is still more useful and predictable.

Comment: @AlexisKing, you should definitely mention accepting the parent context in your answer.

Answer (score 31):

There are a few differences:

- Arrow functions cannot be constructed. While both arrow functions and bound functions both don't have a `.prototype` property, the former do throw an exception when called with `new` while the latter just ignore the bound value and call their target function as a constructor (with the partially applied bound arguments, though) on the new instance.

  ```
  function F() {}
  var f = () => {},
      boundF = F.bind({});
  console.log(new boundF(), new boundF instanceof F) // {}, true
  console.log(new f) // TypeError
  ```
- Arrow functions do have lexical `arguments`, `new.target` and `super` as well (not only lexical `this`). A call to an arrow function does not initialise any of those, they are just inherited from the function the arrow function was defined in. In a bound function, they just refer to the respective values of the target function.
- Arrow functions don't actually bind a `this` value. Rather, they don't have one, and when you use `this` it is looked up like a variable name in the lexical scope. This does allow you to lazily define an arrow function while `this` is not yet available:

  ```
  class X extends Object {
      constructor() {
           var f = () => this, // works
               boundF = function(){ return this; }.bind(this);
  //                                                    ^^^^ ReferenceError
           super(); // initialises `this`
           console.log(f(), f() == this); // {}, true
      }
  }
  new X;
  ```
- Arrow functions cannot be generator functions (though they can return generators). You can use `.bind()` on a generator function, yet there is no way to express this using an arrow function.

Answer (score 9):

Here is one more subtle difference:

Arrow functions can return a value without using the 'return' keyword, by omitting the {} braces following the => immediately.

```
var f=x=>x;           console.log(f(3));  // 3
var g=x=>{x};         console.log(g(3));  // undefined
var h=function(x){x}; console.log(h(3));  // undefined
var i=x=>{a:1};       console.log(i(3));  // undefined
var j=x=>({a:1});     console.log(j(3));  // {a:1}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a particularly useful answer. Yes - curly braces can be omitted - and that's convenient but that's just a difference on syntax, not functionality.

Comment: I think this is an excellent answer especially if you're not across all short-hand syntax