# Binding different this scope to ES6 => function operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

After experimenting with inheriting contexts with the => feature that ES6 gives us I noticed that the this context can never be changed.
Example:

```
var otherContext = {
  a: 2
};
function foo() {
  this.a = 1;

  this.bar = () => this.a;

}

var instance = new foo;
instance.bar(); // returns 1
instance.bar.bind(otherContext)(); // returns 1
```

Without the => operator and using the function keyword:

```
function foo() {
  this.a = 1;

  this.bar = function () {
    return this.a;
  }
}
var instance = new foo;
instance.bar(); // returns 1
instance.bar.bind(otherContext)(); // returns 2
```

Therefore, if we receive a function from an external call or just have a function in a variable, how can we be sure if we are going to be able to bind a different this to it or if it will just inherit it from somewhere?

It sounds dangerous that javascript does not tell you anything, one might fall for a VERY subtle and difficult bug.

Comment: I can't really see a question in there, is there something you doesn't understand about this behavior?

Comment: Yeah, this is my question:
how can we be sure if we are going to be able to bind a different this to it or if it will just inherit it from somewhere?
I added a question mark to clarify

Comment: It's rather unusual that you're going to receinve a fat arrow function from some external source - and if so, it's not designed to be callable in other context.

Comment: If you're developing a method that receives a callback where the `this` value needs to be set, it's your job to document the method properly and it's the user's job to read the documentation and use the correct type of function.

Comment: An arrow function is [just as good as a bound function in that regard](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32535110/1048572).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is effectively just new syntax for `bind`, so this doesn't introduce anything new in the way of gotchas.

```js
var otherContext = {
  a: 2
};
function foo() {
  this.a = 1;
  this.bar = function () { return this.a }.bind(this);
}

var instance = new foo;
log(instance.bar()); // returns 1
log(instance.bar.bind(otherContext)()); // returns 1

function log(value) { 
  document.body.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(value)
  );
}
```

> Therefore, if we receive a function from an external call or just have a function in a variable, how can we be sure if we are going to be able to bind a different this to it or if it will just inherit it from somewhere?

Because either:

1. You'll have written that function in the first place *or*
2. You'll have written a specification for how to call your function so that people know to pass in a function which makes use of `this` from a context you choose.

Comment: Your numbered points express my comment much more succinctly, +1.

Answer (score 8):

When using the `function` keyword, the rules binding `this` are fairly straight forward.

Either the invoking call sets `this` (be it through `.call`, `.apply` or JavaScript setting `this` when the function is called as a method) or `this` gets a well-known value:

- In normal mode, `this` will be the window object.
- In strict mode, `this` will be undefined.

With arrow functions, the rule is even simpler.

- There is no `this` keyword.  (nor arguments, or a few others)

Which means that, inside an arrow function, `this` is always bound to the outside context, because that is where `this` comes from.

So, in summary:

When using arrow functions, the value of `this` always comes from the outside context.

Comment: No arguments in arrow functions?

Comment: Arrow functions can, of course, receive arguments.  However, they don't get the auto-created `arguments` object that  is auto-created when using the `function` keyword.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments