# Can you bind 'this' in an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I've been experimenting with ES6 for a while now, and I've just come to a slight problem.

I really like using arrow functions, and whenever I can, I use them.

However, it would appear that you can't bind them!

Here is the function:

```
var f = () => console.log(this);
```

Here is the object I want to bind the function to:

```
var o = {'a': 42};
```

And here is how I would bind `f` to `o`:

```
var fBound = f.bind(o);
```

And then I can just call `fBound`:

```
fBound();
```

Which will output this (the `o` object):

```
{'a': 42}
```

Cool! Lovely! Except that it doesn't work. Instead of outputting the `o` object, it outputs the `window` object.

So I'd like to know: can you bind arrow functions? (And if so, how?)

---

I've tested the code above in Google Chrome 48 and Firefox 43, and the result is the same.

Comment: The whole point of arrow functions is that they use the `this` of their parent scope.

Comment: It is probably just a failure of the language not throwing an syntax error if you use `this` in an arrow function.

Comment: @ceving No, there are lots of case where it's extremely helpful that they use the `this` of their parent scope. Event handlers is the most common situation I've had, but I'm sure there are lots of others too.

Comment: Yes, in the absence of arrow functions, such code patterns as `var that = this;` or `var self = this;` before storing an anonymous function for later use were quite common! It was workable but awkward, and arrow functions get rid of that non-standard albeit widely-used boilerplate.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

You cannot *rebind* `this` in an arrow function. It will always be defined as the context in which it was defined. If you require `this` to be meaningful you should use a normal function.

From the [ECMAScript 2015 Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> Any reference to arguments, super, this, or new.target within an ArrowFunction must resolve to a binding in a lexically enclosing environment. Typically this will be the Function Environment of an immediately enclosing function.

Answer (score 81):

To be complete, you **can** re-bind arrow functions, you just can't change the meaning of `this`.

`bind` still has value for function arguments:

```
((a, b, c) => {
  console.info(a, b, c) // 1, 2, 3
}).bind(undefined, 1, 2, 3)()
```

Try it here: 
http://jsbin.com/motihanopi/edit?js,console

Comment: Is there a way to detect or use whatever object the (arrow) function is bound to, without referencing `this` (which is, of course, defined lexically)?

Comment: Use an argument for context:
((context) => {
  someOtherFunction.apply(context)
}).bind(willBeIgnored, context)()

Answer (score 17):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target). Arrow functions are always anonymous.

This means you cannot bind a value to `this` like you want.

Answer (score 15):

**description: Stijn de Witt**

You cannot use `bind` to change the value of `this` inside an arrow function. However, you can create a new regular function that does the same thing as the old arrow function and then use `call` or `bind` to re-bind `this` as usual.

We use an `eval` call here to recreate the arrow function you pass in as a normal function and then use `call` to invoke it with a different `this`:

**code: me**

```js
const func = v => console.log(this);
const obj = {value: 10};

function arrowBindOld(context, fn) {
  let arrowFn;
  (function() {
    arrowFn = eval(fn.toString());
    arrowFn();
  }).call(context);
}
arrowBindOld(obj, func);
```

update

```js
const f = v => console.log(this, v);
const o = {value: 10};

/* new */
function arrowBind(context, fn) {
  const arrowFnString = fn.toString();
  return (function() {
    return eval(arrowFnString);
  }).call(context);
}
const fBound = arrowBind(o, f);
fBound(10);

/* use prototype */
Function.prototype.arrowBind = function(context) {
  const arrowFnString = this.toString();
  return (function() {
    return eval(arrowFnString);
  }).call(context);
}
const fBoundProto = f.arrowBind(o);
fBoundProto(20);
```

Answer (score 9):

For years, js developers struggled with context binding, asked why `this` changed in javascript, so much confusion over the years due to context binding and the difference between the meaning of `this` in javascript and `this` in most of the other OOP languages.

All this leads me to ask, why, why! why would you wan't to rebind an arrow function! Those where created specially to solve all this issues and confusions and avoid having to use `bind` or `call` or whatever other way to preserve the scope of the function.

**TL;DR**

No, you cannot rebind arrow functions.

Comment: Arrow functions were created first of all to provide a cleaner and faster syntax. Think lambda-calculus. Too bad the OO-zealots that pester the life of functional JS programmers grabbed the opportunity to take away the freedom to specify the invocation context.

Comment: Using `this` isn't functional. lambdas should be `arguments => output`. If you need some external context, pass it in. The very existence of `this` is what facilitated all of the shoehorning of OO patterns into the language. You would never have heard the term "javascript class" without it.

Comment: You **can** rebind arrow functions. Just not `this`.

Comment: Here is one use case for rebinding:
`describe("Test suite", () => {
  before(function () {
    if (conditionIsNotMet) this.skip(); // skip the suite
  }
});`
If you change that function to arrow function, this.skip is lost.

Answer (score 5):

Short, You **CANNOT** bind arrow functions, but read on:

Imagine you have this arrow function below which prints `this` on the console:

```
const myFunc = ()=> console.log(this);
```

So the quick fix for this would be using normal function, so just change it to:

```
function myFunc() {console.log(this)};
```

Then you can bind it to any lexical environment using `bind` or `call` or `apply`:

```
const bindedFunc = myFunc.bind(this);
```

and call it in case of `bind`.

```
bindedFunc();
```

There are also ways to using `eval()` to do it, which strongly **not recommended**.

Comment: `function myFunc` is behaviorally different in ways besides being bindable; a closer match would be `const myFunc = function() {...}`. I'm also curious what you mean by using eval, since that's an approach I don't think any answers have shared here before - it'd be interesting to see how that's done, and then read why it's so strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

I asked the same question a couple days ago.

You cannot bind a value since the `this` is already bound.

[Binding different this scope to ES6 => function operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284596/binding-different-this-scope-to-es6-function-operator?noredirect=1#comment54383518_33284596)

Comment: "since the this is already binded" - In regular functions `this` is bound too. The point is that in arrow functions it has no **local** binding.

Answer (score 3):

[Do ES6 Arrow Functions Really Solve “this” In JavaScript](https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/)

The above link explains that arrow functions `this` doesn't change with `bind, call, apply` functions.

It is explained with a very nice example.

run this in `node v4` to see the "expected" behavior,

```
this.test = "attached to the module";
var foo = { test: "attached to an object" };
foo.method = function(name, cb){ 
    // bind the value of "this" on the method 
    // to try and force it to be what you want 
    this[name] = cb.bind(this); };
foo.method("bar", () => { console.log(this.test); });
foo.bar();
```

Comment: // run this in node v4 to see the "expected" behavior this.test = "attached to the module"; var foo = { test: "attached to an object" }; foo.method = function(name, cb){ // bind the value of "this" on the method // to try and force it to be what you want this[name] = cb.bind(this); }; foo.method("bar", () => { console.log(this.test); }); foo.bar();

Comment: What's interesting here is to try this and then try it again replacing foo.method('bar', () => { console.log(this.test); }); with foo.method('bar', function () { console.log(this.test); }); - the first version logs "attached to the module" and the second logs "attached to the an object" - I really prefer the more stable treatment of "this" using arrow functions. You can still achieve the other effects using different patterns and the results are more readable and predictable IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is better solution

```
var f = (vm=this) => console.log(vm);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this example help to you :

```js
let bob = {
   _name: "Bob",
   _friends: ["stackoverflow"],
   printFriends:(x)=> {
      x._friends.forEach((f)=> {
         console.log(x._name + " knows " + f);
      });
   }
}

bob.printFriends = (bob.printFriends).bind(null,bob);
bob.printFriends();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it's meant to be impossible to bind an object to an arrow function, never say never; I figured a hack that just might work.

```js
function arrowToRegularFn(callback) {
    let _callback = callback
    const stringifiedCallback = callback.toString()
    const isArrowFn = !stringifiedCallback.trim().startsWith("function")
    if (isArrowFn) {
        const isParamsInParantheses = stringifiedCallback.trim().startsWith("(")
        const [fnParams, ...fnBody] = stringifiedCallback.split("=>")
        _callback = eval("(function" + (!isParamsInParantheses ? "(" : "") + fnParams + (!isParamsInParantheses ? ")" : "") + "{" + fnBody.join("=>") + "})")
    }
    return _callback
}

// test cases

// our object to bind
const quiver = { score: 0 }

let arrow, regular;

// test - 1
arrow = () => this.score++
regular = arrowToRegularFn(arrow).bind(quiver)
regular()
console.log(quiver.score) // 1

// test - 2
arrow = (x, y) => this.score = x + y
regular = arrowToRegularFn(arrow).bind(quiver)
regular(1, 2)
console.log(quiver.score) // 3

// test - 3
arrow = (x, y) => { this.score = x + y }
regular = arrowToRegularFn(arrow).bind(quiver)
regular(3, 4)
console.log(quiver.score) // 7

// test - 4
arrow = function(x, y) { this.score = x + y }
regular = arrowToRegularFn(arrow).bind(quiver)
regular(5, 6)
console.log(quiver.score) // 11
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Normal bind:

```
tag.on("Initialized", function(tag) {
   nodeValueChanged(tag, currentNode)
}.bind(currentNode))
```

Arrow function bind:

```
tag.on("Initialized", (tag => { nodeValueChanged(tag, currentNode) }).bind(currentNode))
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions always have `this` based on its closest non-arrow function irrespective of where it is called. If there is no non-arrow parent it always refers to the global object.

Answer (score 0):

While you are calling the arrow function using call/bind/apply it's doesn't point to the object which you are passing.

```
var obj = {a:1};
var  add=(b)=>{
return this.a + b;
// basically here this.a will be undefined as it's trying to find in one level up which is parents of this function that is window.
}

add.call(obj,2);
```

So that's why passing object doesn't work in arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

Binding Arrow Functions the dirty way:

```js
var obj = { a: 1, b:2 };

obj.c = (function (){return ()=>{console.log("bind",this)}}.bind(obj))()

obj.c()
```