# _.attempt() is returning an error where try/catch is not

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I've tried replacing a try catch block with lodash' _.attempt() to clean up my server code some

```js
let target = (_.attempt(fs.statSync( "path" ) ) );
```

is returning an error when the try / catch equivalent is not

I've tried with the asynch version as well, if I'm using _.attempt() incorrectly it is not clear to me, suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lodash's [`_.attempt()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#attempt) expects a function to invoke as the 1st parameter, and the arguments to the function as the 2nd:

```
let target = _.attempt(function(path) {
  fs.statSync(path);
}, "path");
```

Or the shortened version suggested ing [jmmygoggle's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645461/attempt-is-returning-an-error-where-try-catch-is-not/41649396?noredirect=1#comment83221623_41649396):

```
let target = _.attempt(fs.statSync, "path");
```

Instead of a method to invoke, you've passed the result of `fs.statSync("path")`, which throws an error that `_.attempt()` can't handle.

Comment: Looking back at the documentation after your explanation and it looks so obvious, thanks for explaining it so clearly!

Comment: A more brief equivalent similar to the original: `let target =
 _.attempt(fs.statSync, "path");`

Comment: @jmmygoggle isn't it safer to use bind, i.e const target =  _.attempt(fs.statSync.bind(fs) , "path")

Comment: @sktguha Functions without `this` references may not require `bind()` and there are likely rare scenarios where it is actually undesirable so I'd only add that extra behavior/restriction if you require it.

Comment: ok that makes sense, but in future the `statSync` function may change to reference `this` right ? so it may break then.

also curious what are the rare situations it is undesirable ?

Comment: One undesirable reason to use this broadly or generically to be "safer" could be related to future changes you mentioned. If a method was altered to arrow function syntax (`=>`), using the `bind` method could be pointless and misleading for `this` context, giving a false sense of security. E.g this answer on [non-rebindable `this` in an arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33308151/1575421)

Comment: @jmmygoggle ohh wow that is really helpful. Thanks! 
TIL that arrow functions cannot be rebinded. I knew earlier that they can't be used as a constructor.