# How can I set the this value of a function?

Tags: javascript, closures

In my main.js, I have:

```
import listeners from "./listeners"
listeners.call(this)
```

and my `listeners.js` is:

```
import _ from "lodash"

const listeners = () => {
  console.log("this", this)
}

export default listeners
```

When it runs, it doesn't have the right `this` value in the `listeners` function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change the arrow function to a traditional `function() {...}` - see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-arrow-functions

Comment: in general, you can use Function's `bind` method (which doesn't technically change the `this` in the function, it creates a new function with `this` set as you require)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have the right `this` since an ArrowFunction does not define local bindings for `this`.

You could find some information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this) and the spec [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation).