# arrow-functions as class property, cannot get ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class ImageGridList extends React.Component {
nodeRef = null
say = () => {
    console.log(this.nodeRef)
}
render() {
    let that = this;
    return (
        <div style={{height: '100px', width: '100px', border: '1px solid blue' }}
             onClick={this.say} ref={ node => this.nodeRef = node }
        />
    )
}
```

when you click, this.nodeRef is undefined.
The 'this' object in say function not equal render function's this.

```
onClick={this.say.bind(this)} ref={ node => this.nodeRef = node }
```

will be ok!

```
constructor(props){
 super(props)
 this.say = this.say.bind(this)
}
```

undefined also.
the .babelrc file is

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": [
          "last 1 Chrome versions"
        ],
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    ["transform-es2015-arrow-functions", {"spec": true}],
    ["transform-class-properties", { "spec": false }],
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    ["transform-runtime", {
      "helpers": true,
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": false
    }]
  ]
},
```

may be something wrong

Comment: I am getting <div data-reactroot="" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid blue;"></div> when clicked on blue bordered box

Comment: so sad.may be my .babelrc is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `this` instance with `that` instance in this line:

`onClick={this.say} ref={ node => this.nodeRef = node }`

will be:

`onClick={that.say} ref={ node => that.nodeRef = node }`

Comment: I hope to understand why. not how to resolve it.
change arrow function with bind(this) will be ook.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Arrow functions do not have their own this. 
bind method binding your specified context to function, but: [Can you bind arrow functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-arrow-functions)

Comment: yes, i understand. but say's this should be equal render's this