# how to bind using arrow notation

Tags: javascript, bind, arrow-functions

I have the following object:

```
const person={
   name: 'jordan',
   greet: function(){console.log('hello, ' + this.name)}
}
```

I know I can do the following:

```
const greet = person.greet.bind(person)
```

I'm trying to bind person using arrow notation.  Is it possible?

I thought maybe

```
const greet = person.greet(()=>(person.greet))
```

or

```
const greet = person.greet(()=>(function(){person.greet}))
```

but both of those give immediate execution and greet remains undefined

Comment: that's true, I can go person.greet() but I want to define a const called greet and be able to greet() with this being bound to person.  I can do this without using => and was wondering how to do it with =>

Comment: @GeorgeJempty actually, he does need bind. When you pass a method from an object, `this` refers to the global object.

Comment: Arrow notation does not pass a ‘this’ in the way you’d expect regular function notation to pass it ‘()=>function (){}’ is almost never correct.

Comment: `person.greet()` has no `return`

Comment: You can do this: `var g = person.greet.bind((() => person)())` but I have no idea why you would want to. It's essentially the same as `person.greet.bind(person)`. It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish that you can't do just by binding directly to `person`

Comment: @Mark_M, that's great.  can you break this down and explain?  With => notation I though we had parameters being passed () and something returned => ()  You have ...bind(   (   () => person)  ()  )   oh, wait, I think I see.  Within bind return person immediately ()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you bind arrow functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-arrow-functions)

Comment: @DCR it's not that great really — it's just an immediately involved function that returns `person` so rather than binding to `person` you're binding to the result of this function…which is `person`. It's extra code that doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Thanks, I get that.  Just trying to better understand what's going on under the hood