# How to stop binding every handler and declaring variable 'that'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, bind, handler

I feel doing unnecessary routine, when I bind variables

```
this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
```

or declare `that = this` in order to use current object in an async handler.

Is there a way to handle this routine in a prototype?

Comment: Don't you prefer arrow functions deliberately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm very new to React, however, I know that using arrow functions simplifies this work:

```
import React from 'react';

class Input extends React.Component {

 handleInputChange = () => {
  // do something 
}
 render() {
   return(
     <div>
       <input onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
     </div>  
   )
 }
```

this way you don't need to bind the method in the constructor.

See more in this discussion: [Can you bind arrow functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the fine answer that PolinaC gave, you could use a proxy:

```
class MyClass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        return new Proxy(this, {
            get(obj, prop) {
                return typeof obj[prop] === 'function' ? obj[prop].bind(obj) : obj[prop];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can derive your class or component from AdvancedComponent:

```
import { Component } from 'react';

class AdvancedComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        AdvancedComponent.BindDirectPrototypeMethods(this);
    }    

    static BindDirectPrototypeMethods(obj) {
        const prot = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
        const methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prot).filter(m => {
            return typeof prot[m] === 'function' && m !== 'constructor';
        });

        methods.forEach( m => {
            obj[m] = obj[m].bind(obj);
        })
    }
}

export default AdvancedComponent;
```

This will make `this` available in every method even in the context of other object.

Comment: Just curious. Why do you need a static method? Can you just not do in your `AdvancedComponent` constructor the following code `this.BindDirectPrototypeMethods()`?  And in the Bind method do `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)`?