# Passing data object to fire event

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapbox GL and the doc states:

> Adds a listener to a specified event type.
>
> Parameters:
>
> **type**(string) The event type to add a listen for.
>
> **listener**(Function) The function to be called when the event is fired. The listener function is called with the data object passed to 
>   fire , extended with  target and  type properties.

Source: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#evented#on

So if I do:

```
map.on('click', 'somelayer', { customData: 'foo' }, customFunction);
```

I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: i.call is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the bind:

```
map.on('click', customFunction.bind({customData: 'foo'}))
```

Or if you want to save the context, you can use a wrapper:

```
function extend(fn, data) {
  return (e) => {
    e.data = data
    fn(e)
  }
}
map.on('click', extend(customFunction, {
  customData: 'foo'
}))
```

[ http://jsfiddle.net/tu570Lgz/ ]

Comment: What about if we use arrow functions? See http://jsfiddle.net/oy8j9L75/ customData isn't passed to customfunction.

Comment: @ToniBCN You cannot rebind this in an arrow function - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33308151/4989460

Answer (score -2):

You need to drop the `{customData: 'foo'}`:

```
map.on('click', 'somelayer', customFunction);
```

mapbox-gl tries to execute your object as a function.

Comment: Of course it works if i drop that but i need to pass data.

Comment: Where do you want to pass data to?