# function declare as a arrow function, later want to rebind with other object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

```
let bob = {
   _name: "Bob",
   _friends: ["stackoverflow"],
   printFriends() {
      this._friends.forEach((f)=> {
         console.log(this._name + " knows " + f);
      });
   }
}
```

its working fine when I call `bob.printFriends();`

```js
 let bob = {
       _name: "Bob",
       _friends: ["stackoverflow"],
       printFriends() {
          this._friends.forEach((f)=> {
             console.log(this._name + " knows " + f);
          });
       }
    }
bob.printFriends();
```

but when I change `bob` object `printFriends` function to arrow function :

```
let bob = {
   _name: "Bob",
   _friends: ["stackoverflow"],
   printFriends:()=> {
      this._friends.forEach((f)=> {
         console.log(this._name + " knows " + f);
      });
   }
}
```

If I do not rebind then `this` inside the `printFriends` refer to `window` object. Thats why I am trying to rebind `printFriends`

```
bob.printFriends = bob.printFriends.bind(bob);
```

then `bob.printFriends()` is not working as per expectation, giving error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Object.printFriends (:5:19)
    at :1:5

```js
let bob = {
   _name: "Bob",
   _friends: ["stackoverflow"],
   printFriends:()=> {
      this._friends.forEach((f)=> {
         console.log(this._name + " knows " + f);
      });
   }
}

bob.printFriends = bob.printFriends.bind(bob);
bob.printFriends();
```

Comment: Why do you want to bind the arrow function? Just call bob.printFriends() without the binding.

Comment: without binding ```this``` is reffer to ```window```

Comment: @JaisaRam , see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52907064/6222075