# Why we don't need to bind the arrow function in React?

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

We all know that we need to bind function in React to make it work. I do know why do we need to bind it.

But I'm not sure why we don't need to bind arrow function.

Example:
Using arrow function (No bind in required)

```
handleClick = () => {
  this.setState({
    isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn
  });
```

};

Now, Using function (Bind is required)

`this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);`

```
handleClick() {
  this.setState({
    isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn
  });
```

};

I'm not asking why we need bind in function. I just want to know why binding is not required in arrow function.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you bind arrow functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply because arrow function does not have the following in its context:

- this
- arguments
- super
- new.target

So when you reference this inside an arrow function it treat **this** as any other variable and look for its declaration in its scope first and it can not find it so it search the upper scope which is the **this** referring to the react component class which what is required so we do not need to bind the **this** to the class.

Comment: Then why can 't we use `this` in arrow functions in objects?

Answer (score 11):

To quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not have its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or
>   `new.target`. These function expressions are best suited for non-method
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Further,

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own `this` value (based on how function was called, a new object in the case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode function calls, the base object if the function is called as an "object method", etc.). This proved to be less than ideal with an object-oriented style of programming.

So basically, the reason we don't need to bind is because `this` does not exist in the context of the arrow function. So, it goes up to the next level and uses the `this` it finds there.