# TypeError: Cannot read property '$http' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

Trying to use vue-resource but i am etting the error described in the title. The code below is in utils section called `network.js`:

```
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

const getConfig = () =>{
  console.log('its working');
  // GET /someUrl
  this.$http.get('https://fdsdfsdf-685a-45ed-8665-9847e0dbce0d.mock.pstmn.io/getConfig')
  .then(response => {

    // get body data
    this.config = response.body;

   }, response => {
     // error callback
   });
};

//Export login so other classes can use it
export{
  getConfig
}
```

And this the code where it gets called. It exists in one of my routes called `Admin.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="admin">
    <h1>This is admin page area</h1>
    <p>This is the data: {{this.config}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import{getConfig} from "../utils/network";

export default{

  data: function () {
    return {
      config: [{}]
    }
  },
  created:function(){
      getConfig();
    }
}
</script>
```

I am using it as they describe in the example i am not really sure what i am missing?

Answer (score 2):

- `network.js` is missing a call to `Vue.use(VueResource)`, as [documented](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/057b1a5/docs/config.md#webpackbrowserify) for Webpack projects:

  ```
   import Vue from 'vue'
   import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

   Vue.use(VueResource)
  ```
- And `getConfig()` is an arrow function, which *permanently* binds a lexical `this` (callers [cannot rebind `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33308151/6277151)), and `this` is `undefined` in the scope of `network.js`.

  If you intended for callers (i.e., the components) to specify itself as the context via [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/call), you'd have to declare `getConfig` as a regular function:

  ```
   // network.js
   const getConfig = function() { ... }  // option 1
   function getConfig() { ... }          // option 2

   // MyComponent.vue > script
   import { getConfig } from '../utils/network.js'

   export default {
     created() {
       getConfig.call(this)
     }
   }
  ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/61qln0nv2r)

Another solution is to use [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) so that you could call `this.getConfig()` (without passing the context):

```
    // network.js
    const getConfig = function() { ... }  // option 1
    function getConfig() { ... }          // option 2

    const getConfigMixin = {
      methods: {
        getConfig
      }
    };

    export { getConfigMixin }

    // MyComponent.vue > script
    import { getConfigMixin } from '../utils/network.js'

    export default {
      mixins: [getConfigMixin],
      created() {
        this.getConfig()
      }
    }
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/p3mqyrn047)