# TypeError: Cannot read property '$http' of undefined - VUEJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I can’t access `this.$http` in filters:

```
<v-sheet height="500">
  <v-calendar :now="today" :value="today">
    <template v-slot:day="{ date }">
      <template v-for="event in eventsMap[date]">
        <v-menu :key="event.Ref" full-width offset-x>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <div v-ripple v-  v-on="on" >{{event | searchActivity}}</div>                    
          </template>
        </v-menu>
      </template>
    </template>
  </v-calendar>
</v-sheet>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
import Vue from "vue";
Vue.filter("searchActivity", function(val) {
  var params = {
    ProblemsID: val.ActivityRef
  };
  this.$http
    .post(auth.API_URL + "api/Problems/Activity", params, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.getAuthHeader()
      }
    })
    .then(
      response => {
        this.activityList = response.body;
      },
      response => {
        if (response.Status === true) {
          this.text1 = response.body.ResponseMessage;
          this.snackbar = true;
        } else {
          this.text1 = response.statusText;
          this.snackbar = true;
        }
      }
    );
  this.Obj = this.activityList.ActivityName;

  return this.Obj;
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53797498/typeerror-cannot-read-property-http-of-undefined

Comment: I thınk this solution is true but ı am new a vuejs , ı am working a singlepage application so ı didnt work this solution  but thank you for help  :)

Answer (score 0):

To quote from the Vue.js docs:

> Vue.js allows you to define filters that can be used to apply common text formatting.

Vue.js filters do not have access to `this` as they are pure functions. Meaning you can't use any injections inside filters.

Furthermore, filters must be synchronous, meaning you can't do HTTP calls or anything async inside them.

Filters are normally used to format text values like money, numbers, date or other common presentable information.

To solve your issue, you cannot use `computed` either. Because they must be synchronous as well, so you are only left with `methods`. But you also can't just call an asynchronous method in the template, so you should map your data first before displaying them. You can do the mapping inside `mounted` or `created` life-cycle methods.

**EDIT: added example**

I feel like a lot is going on in your template, I suggest you split the iteration item to a component, let's call it `EventDayView`:

```html
<template>
  <v-menu :key="event.Ref" full-width offset-x>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <div v-ripple v-on="on">{{ activityList.ActivityName }}</div>                    
    </template>
  </v-menu>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'EventsDayView',
  props: {
    event: { type: Object, required: true }
  },
  data: () => ({
    activityList: null
  }),
  methods: {
    searchActivity (val) {
      // Your search activity API call
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.searchActivity(this.event).then(response => {
      this.activityList = response.body;
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Later on you could use it like this:

```html
<v-sheet height="500">
  <v-calendar :now="today" :value="today">
    <template v-slot:day="{ date }">
      <template v-for="event in eventsMap[date]">
        <EventDayView :key="event.Ref" :event="event" />
      </template>
    </template>
  </v-calendar>
</v-sheet>
```

You really ought to think about components first than reaching out to smaller stuff like `filters` or `directives` usually `components` are what you need.

Comment: thank you for helping me, I understand , Can you give me example ?

Comment: I added an example for you, you might want to change some stuff.