# 'this' keyword is not assigned proper scope even when bound

Tags: javascript, object, this, bind

I'm trying to understand the difference between regular javascript functions and arrow function. I have implemented code on js bin to see the outcome.

The issue is, I have a normal function and an arrow function as methods inside an object. I'm calling them being in the window scope. The first function call is working fine as I have expected. But in the second one, I use the bind method to bind 'john' object to the arrow function. Altho I use bind, it always takes the scope of the window object. Why is that?

```
this.table = 'Window table';
this.room = 'Window room';


let john = {
  room: 'johns room',
  table : 'johns table',

  cleanTable(){
    console.log(`cleaning ${this.table}`);
  },
  cleanRoom : () =>{
    console.log(`cleaning ${this.room}`);
  }

}

john.cleanTable();  
john.cleanRoom.bind(john)();

######### output ##########

"cleaning johns table"
"cleaning Window room"
```

I want both of them to log the same thing which is "cleaning johns table". How can I achieve that?

Comment: There is no `this` in arrow functions. `this` refers to parent context instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-arrow-functions

Comment: Aside the duplicate, don't assign properties to `window` using `this`, it's very error prone. Use `window` instead. Also, please get familiar with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) before use.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to remove the use of arrow function because it changes the context of the scopes:

```js
this.table = 'Window table';
this.room = 'Window room';


let john = {
  room: 'johns room',
  table : 'johns table',

  cleanTable(){
    console.log(`cleaning ${this.table}`);
  },
  cleanRoom(){
    console.log(`cleaning ${this.room}`);
  }

}

john.cleanTable();  
john.cleanRoom.bind(john)();
```

If you still want to use the arrow function then pass that object as a parameter and access the property inside the function:

```js
this.table = 'Window table';
this.room = 'Window room';


let john = {
  room: 'johns room',
  table : 'johns table',

  cleanTable(){
    console.log(`cleaning ${this.table}`);
  },
  cleanRoom : (obj) =>{
    console.log(`cleaning ${obj.room}`);
  }

}

john.cleanTable();  
john.cleanRoom(john);
```

Comment: So basically it means that we cant bind to arrow functions? and does arrow functions always refer to window scope?

Comment: @dmcshehan it is always a good practice to pass the object as a parameter instead of passing the reference through bind. Check the second example.