# React - Arrow function vs bind() and event with argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm a newbie in react (even in JS). I'm made the following code in my `App` class:

```js
nameChangeHandler = (event, personId) => {
//method code
};

render()
{
  <div>
    {this.state.persons.map((person, index) => {
      return <Person
          // nameChangeHandler={(event) => this.nameChangeHandler(event, person.id)}
          nameChangeHandler={this.nameChangeHandler.bind(this, person.id)}
      />
    })}
  </div>
}
```

I'm passing `nameChangeHandler` to `Person` component where I call it in `onChange` event in `input` tag (`<input type="text" onChange={props.nameChangeHandler}/>`)

Application works fine when I pass it in this way:
`nameChangeHandler={(event) => this.nameChangeHandler(event, person.id)}`
 but it doesn't when I do it like this:
`nameChangeHandler={this.nameChangeHandler.bind(this, person.id)}`

It fails with an exception when I'm trying to acces `event.target.value` in `nameChangeHandler` method.

How can I pass event and argument to this method using `bind()` method instead of arrow function?

I've heard we should always use `bind()` approach over the arrow function because an arrow function approach could render component many times.

Is there any special use cases and differences between `bind()` and arrows functions?

Comment: You cannot rebind the arrow function `nameChangeHandler`! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-arrow-functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a matter of timing.

When you use `bind`, the arguments map on to the function you are binding in the order you bind them *followed* by any that are passed to the new function.

When you use an arrow function, you are explicitly passing them in the order you determine.

Your function expects `event` to be the **first** argument, so when you use an arrow you function you pass `event, person.id`. However, when you bind you pass `person.id` (the first argument) and when the function is called with `event` you pass that (as the second argument).

This means you arguments end up the wrong way around.

Since you *only* have `person.id` when you call `bind` and you don't get `event` until later, the only way you can use `bind` for this is to **change the original function** so it accepts the arguments in a different order.

```
nameChangeHandler = (personId, event) => {
```

Comment: Shouldn't be function a normal one instead of arrow function. `nameChangeHandler = (personId, event) => {`. Because he is binding `this`?. Is there any other use of arrow function here?

Comment: @MaheerAli — It depends on if they need to rebind `this` or not. This answer deals with the arguments being wrong.

Comment: @Quentin So after swapping method arguments, the `{(event) => this.nameChangeHandler(person.id, event)` will be equivalent for `{this.nameChangeHandler.bind(this, person.id)}`, wihout any sides effects? Am I right?

Comment: @KamilW — Subject to comments about `this`, yes.