# JavaScript `bind` not working on imported functions/objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bind

There are three files.

1. `context.js` which exports an object passed to `bind`:

```
module.exports = {
    exceptionValue: 99
};
```

2. `strategy.js` that is exports the function I want to call bind on:

```
module.exports = events => {
    if (this.exceptionValue !== 99) {
        throw new Error(this);
    }
    return events;
};
```

3. `index.js` which imports both the previous files:

```
const context = require('./context');
const strategy = require('./strategy');

const strategyWithContext = strategy.bind(context);
return strategyWithContext(events);
```

`events` is a list of JSON objects that are passed to `index.js`. To be more precise, I'm exporting this function from `index.js` and people who call it will provide those events. But it's nothing special, just a list of JSON objects.

The problem is that the `this` reference inside the strategy function isn't working and it's always throwing an exception. I can't access my context object at all. What am I doing wrong? Why isn't it working?

Comment: What behavior are you seeing? Where is events defined in index.js?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that, I just edited the question.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-arrow-functions

Comment: I still looks like events in index.js is not defined.

Comment: Arrow functions were created to keep the context they were created in.
They don't bind to contexts. Use non arrow functions for this.

Comment: @lankovova is right, you cannot bind an arrow function anyway.

Comment: are you using node.js?

Answer (score 6):

You've misidentified the problem. The export is irrelevant.

Arrow functions already bind a `this` value, and you can't override it with `bind()`.

Use a function expression instead of an arrow function.

```
module.exports = function (events) {
    if (this.exceptionValue !== 99) {
        throw new Error(this);
    }
    return events;
};
```

Comment: completely right answer. Helped me a lot. Spent half of day. Thank you Quentin!