# onMouseMove doesn't exit or onMouseUp doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an svg rectangle with 4 resizers on its 4 edges, both the rectangle and the resizers have their onmousedown/onmousemove/onmouseup event listeners.

When I resize the rectangle from the resizers the onmousemove of the resizer doesn't stop when I stop resizing the element or maybe the onmouseup is not triggered.

Here is my code:

The rectangle events used for drag and drop:

```
  onMouseDown = (e) => {
      if ( this.state.isDraggable ) {
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove);
        this.coords = {
          x: e.clientX,
          y: e.clientY
        }
      }
  }

  onMouseUp = (e) => {
    // this.props.updateStateDragging(this.props.id, false);
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove);
    this.coords = {};
  }

  onMouseMove = (e) => {
    const xDiff = this.coords.x - e.clientX;
    const yDiff = this.coords.y - e.clientY;
    this.coords.x = e.clientX;
    this.coords.y = e.clientY;

    this.setState({
      x: this.state.x - xDiff,
      y: this.state.y - yDiff,
    });
  }
```

The resizer events used to resize the rectangle:

```
  onMouseDown = (e) => {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove);
    this.props.updateStateResizing(this.props.id, true);
    this.props.updateStateDragging(this.props.id, false);
  }

  onMouseMove = (e) => {
    if ( this.props.isResizing ){
      this.props.nodeResizer(this.props.id, e.target, e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }
  }

  onMouseUp = (e) => {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove.bind(this));
    if ( this.props.isResizing ){
      this.props.updateStateResizing(this.props.id, false);
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? How can it fix it?

Comment: Can you provide some code how you're adding the mousedown and mouseup events to your component. And how is the property `isResizing` set? My first guess is, this should be a state property and not be provided as component property from outside.

Comment: Here how the mousedown and mouseup are added:
`
return(
        <circle
          onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
          onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}
          onContextMenu={this.onContextMenu}
          id="BottomRight"
          style={style}
          cursor={BottomRight.cursor}
          cx={BottomRight.cx}
          cy={BottomRight.cy}
          r={style.r}
        />
);
`
the `isResizing` is defined at the node level as it is the target of the resize and it could be locked by another component.

Comment: Does dragging have anything to do with the problem - if you remove the dragging code, does the resize problem stay the same?

Comment: I removed the dragging code, and still have the same problem.

Comment: All I can suggest is to edit the question and include a [cut-down but complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)  so that  readers can reproduce the problem and help further.

Answer (score 0):

The call to remove the "mousemove" listener must supply the same function  object as supplied when adding the listener. However

```
this.onMouseMove
```

is not the same function object as

```
this.onMouseMove.bind(this)
```

Try removing `.bind(this)` in the `onMouseUp` code to start with.

---

*Technical Note*

[Rebinding an arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33308121/5217142) does not change the `this` value seen within the arrow function.

Arrow functions always use the lexical `this` value that was in effect at the time they were defined. Syntactically you can call `bind` on an arrow function - they are function objcts and inherit from `Function.prototype` - but the arrow function never uses the `this` value supplied to `bind`.

Comment: I did with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try using settimeout wherever you are using document.removeEventListener like:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove.bind(this));
}, 500);
```

```
    onmousedown = (e) => {
      console.log("D>>>>>", e);
    }

    onmousemove = (e) => {
      console.log("M>>>>>", e);
    }

    onmouseup = (e) => {
      console.log("U>>>>>", e);
    }
```

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-4gqoxc?embed=1&file=index.ts)

Comment: I'm using `removeEventListener` inside the `onMouseUp` which never triggers, this is my main question.

Comment: I have tried the following and it works     onmousedown = (e) => {
      console.log("D>>>>>", e);
    }
  
    onmousemove = (e) => {
      console.log("M>>>>>", e);
    }
  
    onmouseup = (e) => {
      console.log("U>>>>>", e);
    }