# Why setInterval() with a declaration of a function as an argument works differently than with anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, setinterval

I don't understand why using function name in setInterval is not working correctly but passing annonymous function is working just right.

not working example (it's console logging NaN and before calling first time this.counter++ it's returning undefined as it couldn't find the variable?)

```
export class MyClassName {
 counter = 0;

 startInterval(){
   setInterval(this.myFunc , 1000)
 }

 myFunc(){
   this.counter++;
   console.log(this.counter)
 }
}
```

but with startInterval changed like below it's working correctly

```
startInterval(){
  setInterval(() => this.myFunc() , 1000)
}
```

and in html we have

```
<button (click)="startInterval()">Start</button>
```

Comment: Because the `this` has a differnt context in your calls. Try `this.myFunc.bind(this)`.

Comment: Your code will not run as-is. It has more than one syntax error. Please update the code with a working example.

Comment: @ToddChaffee I think it's an excerpt of a class

Comment: @Lain Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: @Kaspazza questions should provide working examples. Otherwise we are guessing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ToddChaffee it is part of code because I am not asking how to make it work (as I wrote it works already) I just wanted to ask why it's working like that. So I just showed a concept.

Comment: @Kaspazza: Not really without context. Probably once `this` refers to your class/namespace and the other time to `window`. Just put a `console.log()` on the `this` and you might find it.

Comment: This is why we need working code. Can't tell what `this` refers to without the context.

Comment: Okay I added more code and I hope it's clear now

Comment: Well basically like I suspected above: the arrow function automatically binds `this` of its context. The normal call does not which leads to `this` being `window` which has no variable `counter` defined. You have to `bind` it yourself explicitly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-arrow-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, you pass in a function reference without running it. When it runs, it runs in the global context where `this` is undefined, or `this` refers to the `Window` object. You can verify that it does in fact refer to the `Window` object by logging the value of `this.constructor.name`:

```js
class MyClassName {
 counter = 0;

 // You are passing in a function name but not running it yet.
 // It will be run in a global context by setInterval.
 startInterval(){
   setInterval(this.myFunc, 1000)
 }

 myFunc(){
   // When run in global context, this no longer refers to our instance.
   console.log(this.constructor.name);
   this.counter++;
   console.log(this.counter)
 }
}

const mc = new MyClassName();

mc.startInterval();
```

In the second example, arrow functions use the `this` of where they are declared, not where they are run. So the `this` of the class is captured below, even though the arrow function will run in the global context.

```js
class MyClassName {
 counter = 0;

 // Arrow functions use the `this` of where they are declared, not where they are run.
 // So the `this` of the class is captured below, even though the arrow function
 // will run in the global context.
 startInterval(){
   setInterval(() => this.myFunc(), 1000);
 }

 myFunc(){
   console.log(this.constructor.name);
   this.counter++;
   console.log(this.counter)
 }
}

const mc = new MyClassName();

mc.startInterval();
```

You can find a pretty good summary of exactly how this works specifically with `setInterval` in the [MDN docs for arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy is with the **this** keyword. In javascript anonymous/arrow functions do not create *this* to reference the caller of the function. while a conventional function declared with *function* keyword will capture the caller of the function in **this**.

Therefore, in your first example the startInterval() is called by the button element, which doesn't have a counter variable. And in the second example the *this* keyword refers to the outer scope *this* which is the window object. I assume MyClassName gets created under the window object, therefore the counter exists.

Further reading:
https://www.codementor.io/dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc

Answer (score -1):

That's because your `this` is calling to the function and therefore `myFunc` is not defined. You can learn about `this` context with a quick search. Some examples: [1](https://blog.pragmatists.com/the-many-faces-of-this-in-javascript-5f8be40df52e), [2](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-understand-the-keyword-this-and-context-in-javascript-cd624c6b74b8).

---

You can verify this by logging `this.myFunc`. The same will happen to `this.counter` if it ever gets called.

```js
let counter = 0;

const startInterval = () => {
  // undefined, and hence it does not exist.
  console.log(this.myFunc);
  setInterval(this.myFunc, 1000);
};

startInterval();

const myFunc = () => {
  this.counter++;
  console.log(this.counter);
};
```

You can simply fix your code by reordering the functions and removing `this`.

```js
let counter = 0;

const myFunc = () => {
  counter++;  // Remove this from here as well.
  console.log(counter);
};

const startInterval = () => {
  // Defined, and hence it works.
  setInterval(myFunc, 1000);
};

startInterval();
```

Comment: This breaks the whole code. A `this` property is different by a closure variable. The correct solution is like indicated by @Lain in comments

Comment: I am just explaining the issue with `this`. There's several ways to attach the counter and function to the `this` context like prototypes, binding, creating a closure above all, having a class, etc...