# `this` not being passed to function when using bind() call() or apply()

Tags: javascript

I'm using React and inside my `componentDidMount() {}` I'm calling an imported function and want to access `this.setState` within it.

Within `componentDidMount`, When I `console.log(this)`, I get the component as expected.

But if I run `myFunction.call(this)`, `console.log(this)` inside myFunction returns `undefined`.

Any ideas why `this` is not being passed correctly?

edit1: adding code.

Component:

```
class Navbar extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        myFunction.call();
    }
}
```

myFunction.js:

```
export const myFunction = () => {
    console.log('this:', this);
}
```

Console output:

```
this: undefined
```

edit2: some people flagged this as a duplicate of "can i bind arrow functions" but myFunction is an arrow function and even if I call it directly instead of using .call() it produces the same result: `this` is undefined.

Comment: Could you post the code please?

Comment: `this` in the context you're invoking the method is `undefined`, you should pass a reference to the target component instead of `this`.

Comment: How about return a value from the imported function and use the returned value to set the state ? even if you need to access something from the component state or props you can pass it as an argument

Comment: Your imported function is an arrow function?

Comment: @AvinKavish - good catch!

Comment: commenters are working in the dark here, please post the code.

Comment: @MattPengelly + others, i posted code that replicates this

Answer (score 1):

Bind the imported function in the constructor:

```
import { myFunction } from './path/to/myFunction';

class Navbar extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
       /* other constrcutor code */
       myFunction = myFunction.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
       myFunction();
    }
}
```

In your `myFunction.js`, convert the ES6 arrow function to a regular ES5 function (see [Can you bind arrow functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-arrow-functions)):

```
export const myFunction = function() {
    console.log('this:', this);
}
```

Comment: when I do this it errors within the constructor saying myFunction is not defined

Comment: Well then clearly your import is either not there or it does not work. That, though, cannot be a result of my suggested changes.