# Return an inactived node back to it's original order when a sibling node is active

Tags: javascript, html, css

Beginner here. So for my class `.active` I am setting the order to -1 in my CSS so that it becomes the top div, it removes the class correctly but I am assuming that the order for the previous active is still -1

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.div');

toggleActive = () =>
{
    if (this.classList.includes("active"))
        this.classList.toggle("active");
    else
    {
        divs.forEach(x => x.classList.remove("active"));
        this.classList.toggle("active");
    }
}

divs.forEach(x => x.addEventListener("click", toggleActive));
```

Basically I have:
**div1 div2 div3 div4 div5** and if the user clicks one it should result as 
**div4 div1 div2 div3 div5**

click again should result 
**div2 div1 div3 div4 div5** but i get instead 
**div4 div2 div1 div3 div5**

CSS:

```
.active
{
    order: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue use your code you need to do this following way.

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.div');

function toggleActive() {
if (this.classList.contains("active"))
        this.classList.toggle("active");
    else
    {
        divs.forEach(x => x.classList.remove("active"));
        this.classList.toggle("active");
    }
}

divs.forEach(x => x.addEventListener("click", toggleActive));
```

Explanation:

1. You can not use an arrow function to bind "this" so you need to use the regular function for that. The reference link, [can you bind 'this' in an arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-this-in-an-arrow-function)
2. You need to use `contains` instead of `includes`.

I have added the code snippet, so that it may help you.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.div');

function toggleActive() {
if (this.classList.contains("active"))
        this.classList.toggle("active");
    else
    {
        divs.forEach(x => x.classList.remove("active"));
        this.classList.toggle("active");
    }
}

divs.forEach(x => x.addEventListener("click", toggleActive));
```

```css
.active
{
    order: -1;
}

div.active{
  color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
1. One
</div>
<div class="div">
2. Two
</div>
<div class="div">
3. Three
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

example with data-set which reduces the lines of code and do remember to enclose it within a flex box for the order effect to word

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-index]');

divs.forEach(x=>x.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    divs.forEach(item=>{  
        item.classList=item.dataset.index==x.dataset.index?"div active":"div"
    })
}))
```

```css
div
{
cursor: pointer;
}

.active
{
    order: -1;
}

div.active{
  color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;">
    <div class="div" data-index="0">
        1. One
    </div>
    <div class="div" data-index="1">
        2. Two
    </div>
    <div class="div" data-index="2">
        3. Three
    </div>
    <div class="div" data-index="3">
        4. Four
    </div>
    <div class="div" data-index="4">
        5. Five
    </div>
</div>
```