# Changing callback of Array.prototype.every() to Arrow Function

Tags: javascript

I'm working in a very simple rules engine that evaluates a series of conditions consisting in an operation and an expected value. The rules are only valid when all conditions in the array are true.

My code (it currently works, actually) looks similar to the following, I just simplified the function bodies to make the question more concise:

```
const isA = (p1, p2, p3) => {
    return false; // Simplified function body, real thing has some logic
};

const isB = (p1, p2, p3) => {
    return false;
};

const getC = (p1, p2, p3) => {
    return 0;
};

const getD = (p1, p2, p3) => {
    return "string";
};

const rule = {
    conditions: [
        { operation: isA, expectedValue: false },
        { operation: isB, expectedValue: false },
        { operation: getC, expectedValue: 0 },
        { operation: getD, expectedValue: "string" }
    ]
};

function isConditionMet(condition) {
    return (
        condition.operation(this.p1, this.p2, this.p3) ===
        condition.expectedValue
    );
}

export const areRuleConditionsMet = (p1, p2, p3) => {
    return rule.conditions.every(isConditionMet, { p1, p2, p3 });
}
```

Basically, `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are used within the operations to generate an actual value to be compared against the expected value to determine if each individual condition is met and if every of them are met, then the exported function would return `true`.

What I would like to do is changing my code so that `isConditionMet` can become an Arrow Function to follow the structure of the rest of the code and also avoid using `this` but my problem is that, obviously, I depend on the `thisArg` of `Array.prototype.every()` to propagate the arguments of `areRuleConditionsMet` to each operation. **Any Ideas?**

Comment: *"Any Ideas?"* Keep it as it is. Not everything has to be an arrow function. Or if `isConditionMet` is kind of fixed (cannot be changed anyway), define it inside `areRuleConditionsMet` and reference `p1`, `p2`, `p3` directly: `return rule.conditions.every(c => c.operation(p1, p2, p3) === c.expectedValue)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-this-in-an-arrow-function

Comment: @epascarello asker wants to *avoid* using `this`, not find another way to use it with arrow functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass an anonymous arrow function to `Array#every()` and make `isConditionMet()` accept another argument containing `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`.

```
const isConditionMet = (condition, params) => (
        condition.operation(params.p1, params.p2, params.p3) ===
        condition.expectedValue
);

export const areRuleConditionsMet = (p1, p2, p3) => {
    return rule.conditions.every(condition => isConditionMet(condition, { p1, p2, p3 }));
}
```

Comment: That is a good point @Klaycon, I used your approach and works as I expected. I also changed isConditionMet to a const + `=>` which is what I wanted my code to look like at the beginning.

Comment: @LucianoM.L. Right, forgot that was the goal here haha. I edited the answer to match the original goal just for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

What I often like to use is functions that create functions (also known as currying):

```
const isConditionMet = (p1, p2, p3) => ({operation, expectedValue}) => 
   operation(p1, p2, p3) === expectedValue
```

And then you can use it like:

```
rule.conditions.every(isConditionMet(p1, p2, p3))
```