# vue bind this to imported rule function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have multi Vue files that share the same string validation check logic like:

```
data(){
        return {
            dialog: false,
            unitEditing:{},
            codeRules:[
                v => !!v || 'can't be empty',
                v => !(/\s/g.test(v)) || 'can't contain space'
            ],
            idRules:[
                v => !!v || 'can't be empty',
                v => !(/\s/g.test(v)) || 'can't contain space',
                v => (this.unitEditing.platform != "unity" || (v=="video" || v=="rewardedVideo")) || "placement for unity should only be video or rewardedVideo"
            ],
        }
    },
```

I think it would be nice that I make a utils file (`../utils/miscUtils.js`) for this:

```
var MiscUtils = {
    rules: {
        codeRules:[
                v => !!v || 'can't be empty',
                v => !(/\s/g.test(v)) || 'can't contain space'
            ],
        idRules:[
                v => !!v || 'can't be empty',
                v => !(/\s/g.test(v)) || 'can't contain space',
                v => (this.unitEditing.platform != "unity" || (v=="video" || v=="rewardedVideo")) || "placement for unity should only be video or rewardedVideo"
            ],
    }
}

export default MiscUtils;
```

So that I could use:

```
import MiscUtils from '../utils/miscUtils'
...
data(){
        return {
                dialog: false,
                unitEditing:{},
                codeRules:MiscUtils.rules.codeRules,
                idRules:MiscUtils.rules.idRules
            }
        },
```

But the thing is that we are referring `this.unitEditing` in our check rules. I also tried

```
idRules:MiscUtils.rules.idRules.bind(this)
```

And it says that `MiscUtils.rules.idRules` is not a function so can not bind.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`idRules` is an `Array`, but you're trying to call [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) on it (`Array` has no `bind` method). But `Function#bind` wouldn't help because the arrow function's context is already bound and [cannot be re-bound](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33308151/6277151).

One solution is to make `idRules` a function that takes a component instance as the argument and returns an `Array`:

```js
var MiscUtils = {
    rules: {
        codeRules: [
                v => !!v || 'can\'t be empty',
                v => !(/\s/g.test(v)) || 'can\'t contain space'
            ],
        idRules: comp => [
                v => !!v || 'can\'t be empty',
                v => !(/\s/g.test(v)) || 'can\'t contain space',
                v => (comp.unitEditing.platform != "unity" || (v=="video" || v=="rewardedVideo")) || "placement for unity should only be video or rewardedVideo"
            ],
    }
}
```

Then in your component:

```js
data() {
  return {
    dialog: false,
    unitEditing: {},
    codeRules: MiscUtils.rules.codeRules,
    idRules: MiscUtils.rules.idRules(this)
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

`idRules` is an array, not a function; to give the individual rules the context of `this`, you'll need to make this misc utils a factory function, so that you could do something like:

```js
var MiscUtils = function () {
  return {
    rules: {
      codeRules: [
        v => !!v || "can't be empty",
        v => !(/\s/g.test(v)) || "can't contain space"
      ],
      idRules: [
        v => !!v || "can't be empty",
        v => !(/\s/g.test(v)) || "can't contain space",
        v => (this.unitEditing.platform != "unity" || (v == "video" || v == "rewardedVideo")) || "placement for unity should only be video or rewardedVideo"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And in the calling part:

```js
{
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      unitEditing: {},
      // Spread the individual rules
      ...MiscUtils.call(this).rules
    }
  }
}
```

Or alternatively, pass the context as a parameter:

```js
var MiscUtils = context => ({
  rules: {
    codeRules: [
      v => !!v || "can't be empty",
      v => !(/\s/g.test(v)) || "can't contain space"
    ],
    idRules: [
      v => !!v || "can't be empty",
      v => !(/\s/g.test(v)) || "can't contain space",
      v => (context.unitEditing.platform != "unity" || (v == "video" || v == "rewardedVideo")) || "placement for unity should only be video or rewardedVideo"
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `mixins`:

miscUtils.js:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            codeRules: [v => !!v || "can't be empty", v => !/\s/g.test(v) || "can't contain space"],
            idRules: [
                v => !!v || "can't be empty",
                v => !/\s/g.test(v) || "can't contain space",
                v =>
                    this.unitEditing.platform != "unity" ||
                    v == "video" ||
                    v == "rewardedVideo" ||
                    "placement for unity should only be video or rewardedVideo"
            ]
        };
    }
};
```

and you can import this file in your vue component and set mixins:

```
import miscUtils from "FILE_PATH";
export default {
    mixins: [miscUtils],
    data() {
        return {
            dialog: false,
            unitEditing: {}
        };
    },
};
```

and now you can use your validation and `this` refer to component instance.

Comment: This one's always better than a utility module given that the rules are meant for the `data` in the first place (at least that seems to be what the OP wants).