# Returning the data of method inside an object in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to separate the concerns in my code. I want to build a config file where i use the same method to set something. Please note that this is just for demo purpose. Is there a way that I could call the function based on either `car` or `bike` of the `config` object selected. If so, could you please guide me?

I was getting `setYear` is undefined error. I want to set the year of car object from the config object. I want to access the `setYear` function using the config object.

```js
const buildConfig = () => {
  const car = {}
  car.label = config['car'].label;
  car.year = config['car'].setYear('2020')
  console.log('car details', car);
}

const config = {
  'car': {
    label: 'Sedan',
    setYear: setYear
  },
  'bike': {
    label: 'Sedan',
    setYear: setYear
  }
}

const setYear = (year) => {
  car.year = year;
}

buildConfig();
```

Comment: Neither car nor bike has a year property?

Comment: @JonasWilms I'm constructing the object by setting the values. So, the car need not have any predefined keys.

Comment: Hope this will help you understand how to solve your issue. [Can you bind `this` in an arrow function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-this-in-an-arrow-function)

Comment: See also [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use **setYear** as normal function and use **this** to access object property

To know why this works with function check this [Can you bind this in an arrow function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-this-in-an-arrow-function)

```js
const buildConfig = () => {
  const car = {}
  car.label = config['car'].label;
  car.year = config['car'].setYear('2020')
  console.log('car details', car);
}

const setYear = function(year) { // Use normal function
  this.year = year; // Use this to assign year
  return this.year; // Return assigned year 
}

const config = {
  'car': {
    label: 'Sedan',
    setYear: setYear
  },
  'bike': {
    label: 'Sedan',
    setYear: setYear
  }
}

buildConfig();
```

Comment: To know why `this` works with `function` check this [Can you bind `this` in an arrow function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-this-in-an-arrow-function)

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Also, I left it as es6 function by  passing down car object to `setYear` function