# ES6 Arrow Functions and jQuery Widget Factory

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, widget, this

I am using [jQuery Widget Factory](https://jqueryui.com/widget/) in my project, and I am trying as much as possible to use ES6 syntax, including arrow functions.

So, how do I reference `this` inside the methods of of the widget?

As a hypothetical example, I would like to convert this code

```
$.widget( "custom.colorize", {
  
  // default options
  options: {
    red: 255,
    green: 0,
    blue: 0
  },

  // The constructor
  _create: function() {

    this.options.green = 128;
  }
});
```

to this code (note that I changed the `_create` function to an arrow function, which will throw an error)

```
$.widget( "custom.colorize", {
  
  // default options
  options: {
    red: 255,
    green: 0,
    blue: 0
  },

  // The constructor
  _create: () => {

    this.options.green = 128;
  }
});
```

So, how can I reference the local variables as this is now not pointing to them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the jquery widget factory doesn't pass in the element in any other way, so you can just use regular anonymous function syntax. Note that the regular syntax is not inherently worse, and because you need a `this` context your only option is the normal way ([since arrow functions can't have a `this` value binded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33308151/)).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an arrow function for a method that you want `this` to be your object or for a method where the caller is explicitly setting `this` to be something you need.

Arrow functions are not just syntax shortcuts.  They change the value of `this` to be the lexical value of `this` when they execute so you should only use arrow functions when you want the new behavior for `this` or when you aren't using `this` at all.

In your case, you should use a regular function definition, not an arrow definition so that caller can appropriately pass you the value of `this`.