# How to bind object in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let obj = {
    a: "obj foo a"
}

this.a = 1

let foo = () => {
    // this.a = 34;
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this); /// this is not bound at all
    }, 100)
}

foo();
var baz = foo.bind(obj);

baz();
obj.a = "The new A value";
```

How to bind an obj to the foo function to access it inside timeout.

Comment: You can't bind `this` in an arrow function, having a lexically defined `this` value is the entire point of arrow functions

Comment: Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-this-in-an-arrow-function

Comment: Heh, you know, everyone has cars with drivers.  But me, I got a self automated car.  It's great!  But you know what would make it better?  If it had a driver....