# Cannot read property '' of undefined (react)?

Tags: reactjs, ajax

I tried binding but it didn't change anything and now I'm out of ideas. The smallest hint would be huge help. Thank you!

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {
 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    persons: [],
    name: '',
    password: '',
  }
  this.handleSubmit3 = this.handleSubmit3.bind(this);
}
```

and the error location (setstate in success function): Cannot read property 'persons' of undefined

```
handleSubmit3 = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var user = this.state.name + '$' + this.state.password;
    
    $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://localhost:44348/api/user/LoginUserCheckPassword',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(user),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        this.setState({persons: this.state.persons, name: this.state.name, password: data});  //error here
                    },
                    error: function (jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log("An error occurred whilst trying to contact the server: " + jQXHR.status + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                    }
                   
                }); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `bind` if you are using `arrow functions`. You can read more about it at [Can you bind 'this' in an arrow function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-this-in-an-arrow-function) question.

The problem is that the `success: function (data)` is not binded nor the arrow function. It means `this` is referencing to the success function - not the class. Using arrow function `success: (data) => {}` should fix your problem.

Something like this:

```js
handleSubmit3 = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var user = this.state.name + '$' + this.state.password;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://localhost:44348/api/user/LoginUserCheckPassword',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: (data) => {
            this.setState({persons: this.state.persons, name: this.state.name, password: data});  //error here
        },
        error: (jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
            console.log("An error occurred whilst trying to contact the server: " + jQXHR.status + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Btw you don't need to set `persons` again from `state.persons` if they were not changed. You can update them independently only with `this.setState({password: data});` and both, `persons` and `name`, won't be affected. You can read more about it in [documentation - State Updates are Merged](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged).

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your method, likewise:

```
this.handleSubmit3 = handleSubmit3.bind(this);
```

Also change definition to function instead of arrow function.

```
function handleSubmit3(e) {
    ...
}
```

You can read more about limitations and use-cases of arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: thank you, I didn't test this because the other answer is somewhat shorter but the material you linked is very useful