# Jquery bind returns this to entire document

Tags: jquery, return, click, this, bind

How to make:

```
$('.x').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

like that:

```
$('.x').on('click', () => {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

but still working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you bind 'this' in an arrow function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-this-in-an-arrow-function)

Comment: I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0):

You could use event parameter which is supplied to the function, and `event.target` will be equal to `this` call in regular function.

```
$('.x').on('click', (event) => {
    console.log($(event.target).attr('id'));
});
```

The reason you can't use `this` is shown below. Link I previously provided shows how complex can be binding of context to arrow function. Jquery uses similar approach for your handlers

```js
var customObject = {
  data: "test"
}

function test(func) {
  func.call(customObject);
}

test(function () 
{
  console.log(this);
});

test(() => {
  console.log(this);
});
```