# Error: Uncaught TypeError: this.beginPath is not a function while defining a prototype function

Tags: javascript

I declared a `CanvasRenderingContext2D` prototype function to clear screen:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.clearScreen = () => {
    //paint the inside area black
    this.beginPath();
    this.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    this.fillStyle = '#000000';
    this.fill();
};
```

However, when I do `ctx.clearScreen()` it shows this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.beginPath is not a function
```

Apperently, using `this` doesn't seems to be right way to access predefined functions. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: You need `function () {` and not `() => {`.

Comment: Okay, I changed it and it works now, any way to bind `this` for use in arrow function?

Comment: @GyanPrakash No.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When using arrow functions in javascript the keyword `this` refers to the parent object `window` in this case.
You need to use a regular anonymous function to fix your issue:

```js
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.clearScreen = function() {
    //paint the inside area black
    this.beginPath();
    this.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    this.fillStyle = '#000000';
    this.fill();
};
```

Comment: Is there any way to bind `this` for arrow functions?

Comment: as per the answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-this-in-an-arrow-function) you cant

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. The only way is going to be using the old fashion `function()` syntax