# JavaScript: OnClick with multiple elements return "windows" under this keyword

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am trying to bind all `<a>` elements to have onclick function. And while variable `a` is a, when I try to use keyword `this` inside of `onclick` it returns me `Window` object.
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
</head>
<body>
<div id="stages">
    <div><p>Część I</p></div>
    <div><a data="audio/01-1-1.mp3">Rozdział  1</a><div></div><p>44:10</p></div>
    <div><a data="audio/02-1-2.mp3">Rozdział  2</a><div></div><p>20:06</p></div>
    <div><a data="audio/03-1-3.mp3">Rozdział  3</a><div></div><p>19:16</p></div>
    <div><a data="audio/04-1-4.mp3">Rozdział  4</a><div></div><p>25:29</p></div>
    <div><a data="audio/05-1-5.mp3">Rozdział  5</a><div></div><p>32:16</p></div>
    <div><a data="audio/06-1-6.mp3">Rozdział  6</a><div></div><p>13:06</p></div>
    <div><a data="audio/07-1-7.mp3">Rozdział  7</a><div></div><p>28:38</p></div>
    <div><a data="audio/08-1-8.mp3">Rozdział  8</a><div></div><p>51:59</p></div>
</div>

<script>
const a = document.querySelector('#stages a')
console.log(a)
a.onclick = () => {
    console.log(this);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this keyword doesn't work with arrow function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you bind 'this' in an arrow function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-this-in-an-arrow-function)

Comment: Change `() =>` to `function ()` and it will work. Arrow functions are transparent towards the outer scope in terms of `this`, they can't have their own `this`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `this`, you need to create a regular anonymous function rather than an arrow function.

```js
const anchors = [...document.querySelectorAll("#stages a")];

anchors.forEach(a => {
   console.log(a);

   a.onclick = function () {
      console.log(this);
   };
});
```

Comment: There is a problem that only first `<a>` is responding and rest doesn't react to cicks.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal, as you're in window closure and you use an arrow function, if you need to have access to your element, you can add a prop to your arrow function like this:

```js
const stages = [...document.querySelectorAll("#stages a")];
stages.forEach((a) => a.onclick = (e) => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
</head>
<body>
<div id="stages">
    <div><p>Część I</p></div>
    <div><a data="audio/01-1-1.mp3"><strong>Rozdział  1</strong></a><div></div><p>44:10</p></div>
    <div><a data="audio/02-1-2.mp3">Rozdział  2</a><div></div><p>20:06</p></div>
    <div><a data="audio/03-1-3.mp3">Rozdział  3</a><div></div><p>19:16</p></div>
    <div><a data="audio/04-1-4.mp3">Rozdział  4</a><div></div><p>25:29</p></div>
    <div><a data="audio/05-1-5.mp3">Rozdział  5</a><div></div><p>32:16</p></div>
    <div><a data="audio/06-1-6.mp3">Rozdział  6</a><div></div><p>13:06</p></div>
    <div><a data="audio/07-1-7.mp3">Rozdział  7</a><div></div><p>28:38</p></div>
    <div><a data="audio/08-1-8.mp3">Rozdział  8</a><div></div><p>51:59</p></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: These are not the same. `this` would be the `<a>` tag that the event listener was attached to, while `event.target` would be the element that was actually clicked. (For example, if you have `<a href="#">Hello <strong>World</strong>!</a>` and you click on the word `World`, then `event.target` would be the `<strong>` tag and not the `<a>`.)

Comment: YAGNI principle, in this specific question, we don't have text wrapped around a tag, so it will work

Comment: Yes but Stack Overflow's main purpose is building a generalized database of common questions and answers to primarily help _future_ readers finding this on Google who may not be aware of that detail (plus, you didn't point it out either). Helping the person who originally asked the question is only a fortunate side-effect. Also, the `G` in YAGNI cannot be assumed here either, how do you know they are not _going to_ need it? Why give them a crippled, misleading tool to start with that falls apart if used generically next time?

Comment: I don't know if they gonna need it and you don't know too.
You have your opinion I have mine, the purpose of this answer is to say that the arrow functions don't have their own scope, but inherits the parent scope and to show how you can get the event in the case you use an arrow function and not to force to use a simple function instead. Anyway I made an effort and edited my answer, does this answer suits you :) P.S. I didn't seen your answer

Comment: Now I upvoted it. Now the answer is a helpful addition to the other answers! And you didn't see an answer from me because I didn't need to post any, there was already an answer by Ar Rakin.