# Why extending property of existing object with arrow function fails

Tags: javascript, function, closures, this, arrow-functions

Why arrow function fails to identify `this` pointer in the following case. I know that regular functions have their own execution scope and `this` but I could not identify why following failed. In the arrow function case, `this` is `undefined`. If someone can shed light, it would be great. Thank you!

PS: This code is just for experimental purposes, not anything serious.

```js
const addProperty = function(op, func) {
  String.prototype.__defineGetter__(op, func);
};

// works
addProperty('upper', function() {
  return this.toUpperCase();
});

// fails to identify this
addProperty('lower', () => {
  return this.toLowerCase();
});
```

Comment: Found the answer after short Google search. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions preserve the `this` of the outside scope. `function` keyword functions, in this context, get the `this` of the object they're put on. That's just what they do.

Comment: To add onto this, if you want to use the arrow function, simply use the `bind` method to explicitly set the `this` value for the arrow function: `addProperty('lower', () => {
  return this.toLowerCase();
}.bind(this));`

Comment: @AndrewShearer Doing that does not work (partially because of the syntax error; you need to wrap that in parentheses) because that still binds it to the outside scope, because that's what the value of `this` is at that point

Comment: @AndrewShearer [You cannot rebind arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33308121/1048572)

Comment: and apparently, you can't rebind arrow functions, good to know, but it does not throw a warning/error/exception