# Unable to access internal object after instantiation

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple code with instantiated objects and I'm exposing some methods via a prototype. Here's the code:

```js
const MyClass = (function() {
  function MyClass() {
    this._obj = {
      1: 'dfvdfvd'
    };
  }

  function get() {
    return this._obj[1];
  }

  MyClass.prototype.take = () => {
    get.call(this);
  }

  return MyClass;
}());

let x = new MyClass();
console.log(x.take())
```

but I keep getting `_obj` as `undefined`. what am I missing here?

Comment: The `this` is not what you think you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `MyClass.prototype.take` is an arrow function, but arrow functions don't have their own `this` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)), thus `this` is the default `window` and `this._obj` is `undefined`. You can either [bind it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-this-in-an-arrow-function), or just make it a regular function like I did below.

Also, make sure to return a value from `MyClass.prototype.take()`, or else you'll get `undefined`.

```js
const MyClass = (function() {
  function MyClass() {
    this._obj = {
      1: 'dfvdfvd'
    };
  }

  function get() {
    return this._obj[1];
  }

  MyClass.prototype.take = function() {
    return get.call(this);
  }

  return MyClass;
}());

let x = new MyClass();
console.log(x.take())
```

Comment: wow...wouldnt have thought about it myself...so stressed out that I even forgot the `return` keyword...

Comment: _“but `this` is `undefined` for all arrow functions”_ — No, that’s not true. They don’t bind their own `this`, but that doesn’t mean that the value is `undefined`.

Comment: `this` in an arrow function is bound lexically. The value of `this` immediately inside an arrow function is identical to the value of `this` immediately outside the arrow function. You cannot use `.bind` to change this value and it’s not `undefined` by default. It is whatever it is outside.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks for the good catch! I've edited my answer to correct that mistake.