# Unable to call funtion from innter html react

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to call function `this.showTool` from my span element but its not working tried

```
super(props);
    this.showTool=this.showTool.bind(this);
```

and arrow function but nothing is working

```
const headerActionsDiv = document.getElementById("headerActionsDiv");
      if (!headerActionsDiv) {
        const headerButtonRegion = document.getElementById("HeaderButtonRegion");
        if (headerButtonRegion) {
          const parentDiv = headerButtonRegion.parentNode;
          if (parentDiv) {
            const headerActionsDiv = document.createElement("div");
            headerActionsDiv.id = "headerActionsDiv"; // Add an ID to prevent duplication
            headerActionsDiv.className = styles.headeractions; // assuming this is your class name
            headerActionsDiv.innerHTML = `
              <span class="${styles.Pointer}" onclick="${this.showTool}">All Tools</span>
            
            `;
            parentDiv.insertBefore(headerActionsDiv, headerButtonRegion); // Insert before headerButtonRegion
          }
        }
      }

 public showTool = () =>
  {
    this.setState({About:false,CategoryShow:false})
  }
```

Comment: is there any error/warning in devtools? anyway, you [cannot rebind `this` in arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33308151/21354514). Also you shouldn't mess with real DOM while using react, especially when the problem is not too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have to create another span element and assign `onClick` event, this explicitly sets event listener.

Try to use linear `if` conditions instead of multiple nested so your code is clean.

```
if (!headerActionsDiv && headerButtonRegion && headerButtonRegion.parentNode) {
    const headerActionsDiv = document.createElement("div");
    headerActionsDiv.id = "headerActionsDiv"; // Add an ID to prevent duplication
    headerActionsDiv.className = styles.headeractions; // assuming this is your class name
    
    /** You have to create new span element */
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.onclick = this.showTool;
    span.textContent = 'All Tools';
    headerActionsDiv.append(span);

    parentDiv.insertBefore(headerActionsDiv, headerButtonRegion); // Insert before headerButtonRegion
}
```