# What are the key differences between ES6 arrow function and the CoffeeScript fat arrow function?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am looking to rewrite some CoffeScript code to ECMAScript 2015 (ES6).

Some syntax is very similar such as fat arrow functions:

```
(param1, param2, paramN) => expression
```

What are the key differences between [ES6 =>](http://mdn.io/arrow) and [CoffeeScript =>](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow)?

It would be good to get a heads up from people who already have been in the same situation (converting arrow functions back and forth) and could point out the pitfalls and mistakes to avoid.

Comment: I think coffee script arrow function is the one which is `fat`, not es6 arrow function :P

Comment: @xyz "An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function)" mdn.io

Comment: Agreed. I get your point.

Comment: I have never used coffee script arrow function. But, regarding es6 arrow function, one thing to notice is, it has no `arguments` variable.

Comment: Looking at those docs, CoffeeScript's implementation only captures a reference to `this` and passes it into a closure. ES6's implemention ensures that the function *has no `this`* and so uses it's parent's lexically-bound `this`. Same goes for `super`, `arguments` and `new.target` - CoffeeScript's fat arrow does not "bind" these

Comment: The official term is ["arrow function"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions) in ES6, no matter what MDN says. There are no "thin" arrows in ES6 (unlike CoffeeScript).

Comment: Given that a coffeescript arrow basically desugars to a bound function (even if they desugar the `bind()` call into a closure), this seems like a duplicate of [What are the differences between ES6 arrow functions and bound functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32535110/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

Fat-arrow functions in CoffeeScript translate to your usual JavaScript functions, and bind `this` to its value in the lexical scope (the scope of definition). Like so:

**CoffeeScript**

```
sum = (a, b) =>
  return a + b
```

**JavaScript transpilation**

```
var sum;
sum = (function(_this) {
  return function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  };
})(this);
```

*Arrow functions in ES2015 always do this `this` binding.*

```
let arrowFunction = () => this.property
```

translates to this in ES5

```
let arrowFunction = (function () { return this.property }).bind(this)
```

Since `this` can't be bound to anything else in arrow functions, they can't be used with the `new` keyword, since that needs to bind `this` to a new object.

In a "normal" JavaScript function (non-arrow) scope, there's access to a special `arguments` variable that is "array like" and is useful to access all the arguments that were passed to the function, regardless of the parameter signature. Of course, this is also true in CoffeeScript fat-arrow functions. In my `sum` example, if someone calls it as `sum(1, 2, 3)`, one can access the third argument by doing `argument[2]`. Arrow functions don't provide `arguments`, but have "rest parameters". The latter exists in CoffeeScript too, they call it "splats".

Both CS fat-arrow functions and JS arrow functions support default parameter values. That's not a difference, I know, but worth mentioning IMO.