# this keyword inside addEventListener callback

Tags: javascript, this, addeventlistener

I read some other answer about this topic but I'm not sure I understand how `this` keyword works inside `addEventListener`.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

function foo() { console.log(this) }

button.addEventListener('click', foo);
```

`foo` is a regular function inside `addEventListener`, it's not a method on `button` object. When `foo` is called should be executed in the context of the global object, therefore `this` should be equal to `window` and not to `button`.

Looks like a situation similar to [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/87pkngau/):

```js
const obj = {
  method: function (cb) {
    console.log('method', this); // `this` === `obj`

    return cb();
  }
};

obj.method(function() {
  console.log('cb', this); // `this` === `window`
});
```

Where `obj` could be considered as `button`, `method` could be `addEventListener` and `cb` the callback inside `addEventListener`.

I know I can use `bind` to change the context of `this` but I want to understand more in depth why it works like that.

Why `this` inside `addEventListener` callback is invoked on the context of the current element instead of the global object?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler

Comment: "*`foo` is a regular function inside `addEventListener`, it's not a method on `button` object.*" - that doesn't matter. If you call `foo()`, then yes you won't get a `this` value (or the window in sloppy mode), but when you use `addEventListener` then it will call the function *on* the button. Just as if in your `obj` example the `method` would do `cb.call(obj)`

Comment: Also consider the old style: `button.onclick = foo`. There the handler actually is a kind of method :-)

Comment: This problematic is very well explained in [**MDN Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_value_of_this_within_the_handler "MDN Web Docs"). *(Updated link of @JayHarris)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While we know that event listeners are executed with 'this' set to the event target, the below lines of code inside the EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent method in the [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget#_Simple_implementation_of_EventTarget) link that you found will answer your question as to how it is implemented.

```
for (var i = 0, l = stack.length; i < l; i++) {
    stack[i].call(this, event);
}
```

The 'stack' array has the callback functions and they are invoked using .call by passing in the event target instance (this) and event as arguments.

Comment: So, when we register an event with `addEventListener`, an object called `EventTarget.listener` is created, which contains all the events. Each event is an array (or a stack) of our callbacks. When a particular event occur, the browser invoke `EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent()` and execute all the callbacks in the stack, using `call()` to change the context of `this` to the element on which the event was bound.

Comment: If anyone was wondering if it is safe to replace `this` with `event.target` or `event.currentTarget`, it absolutely **is** as explained in [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_value_of_this_within_the_handler "MDN Web Docs")

Comment: This makes sense. "this" in function invoking (not the method invoking, arrow function invoking, constructor invoking...) will return global object (window in browser) or undefined in 'strict mode'. There must be somewhere to change the binding context to make "this" point to element when use addEventListener.

Answer (score 22):

If we are using functions which have been defined using function keyword as an event handler, then that event handler function executes in the context of the element on which event was binded

```
button.addEventListener('click', foo);
```

so, in this case, `this` value inside foo will be `button` element.

If we use arrow functions instead of them then `this` value will be the window object

The reason is `this` in an arrow function has the same value as the context in which the arrow function was created

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => { console.log(this) // window } );
```

More about lexical this
[What is lexical 'this'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696686/what-is-lexical-this)

Comment: thanks for mentioning arrow functions and differences between the two in terms of scope

Comment: You're the best. Appreciate the lexical reference.

Answer (score 2):

Event listeners are executed with `this` set to the object that triggered the event, as one listener can listen to events of many objects.

A regular function invocation however does *not* set `this` if the invocation expression does not contain a member access via `.`. In those cases, without `"use strict"` active, `this` will become the global context, which is `window` in the browser.

If you want `this` for `cb` to be `obj`, you could replace `cb()` with `cb.apply(this)`, which would set `cb`'s `this` to that of the enclosing function.

A final warning: these `this` mechanics only work for functions defined with the `function` keyword (and similar mechanics). The `this` inside of an arrow function becomes locked to that of the enclosing scope at the time of definition.

Answer (score 2):

As event handler is a type of callback, they are passed as a parameter to the function. Let's create a simple function and passed one callback as a parameter to it and see how it actually works.

```
    function testCallBack(fn){
       console.log('inside testCallBack');
       fn('Hello I am a callBack')
    }

    testCallBack(foo);

    function foo(param){
      console.log(param);
    }

// Outputs: 
inside testCallBack
Hello I am a callBack
```

**Every scope in JavaScript has a *this* object that represents the calling object for the function.**

That's the reason why `this` inside addEventListener callback is invoked on the context of the current element instead of the global object.
Refer below code for more clear understanding:

```
   function sayNameForAll() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }

    var person1 = {
        name: "Rajat",
        sayName: sayNameForAll
    };

    var person2 = {
        name: "pldg",
        sayName: sayNameForAll
    };

    var name = "Sidd";

    person1.sayName();      // outputs "Rajat" here calling object is person1, so this represents person 1
    person2.sayName();      // outputs "pldg"

    sayNameForAll();        // outputs "Sidd"
```

So when you call `button.addEventListner('click',foo)`, your calling object is `button`.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you can use `bind` or `call` to set `this` to whatever you want, the browser APIs can also call your functions with any value set to `this`. It’s used in a bunch of weird ways and isn’t very consistent. Outside of classes and methods, `this` is more like a secret extra argument to a function. In this case you could avoid needing it by getting the button element from `event.target`.