# function() {} and () => {} , is same?

Tags: javascript

I have a study code that I am currently using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 500).attr('height', 500);

      var data = [30, 20, 40];

      var circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
        .data(data).enter()
        .append('circle')
          .attr('cx', (d, i) => i * 30 + 20)
          .attr('cy', 30)
          .attr('r', d => d / 2)
          .style('fill', 'steelblue');

      circles.on('mouseenter', () => {
        d3.select(this).style('fill', 'red');
      });
      circles.on('mouseout', function() {
        d3.select(this).style('fill', 'steelblue');
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

The `mouseenter` function is not working, but the `mouseout` function is fine.
Please tell me the difference about `function()` {} with () => {}

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Just google it D: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch

Comment: They are not the same, otherwise there'd be no point in having two different things, would there? ;)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the lexical use of `this` in (fat) arrow functions.

Jake explains it perfectly here- [What is lexical 'this'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696686/what-is-lexical-this)

Answer (score 0):

One difference is that function(){} gets it's own `this` where ()=>{} gets the `this` from where it was called. This [article](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/es5-functions-vs-es6-fat-arrow-functions-864033baa1a) explains more in depth the differences between the two.