# Call function in event handler

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting an ID from event handler now I want to call my service method using this ID but I'm getting method undefined error. please correct me because I am new to Angular.
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTaxByCategory' of undefined

**component.ts**

```
categoryChanged(event: any){
  //console.log(event.previousValue);
  this.categoryId = event.value;
  this.taxService.getTaxByCategory(this.categoryId).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
  })
}
```

**service method**

```
public getTaxByCategory(categoryId: number): Observable < any > {
  return this.taxes = this.apollo.watchQuery<Query["taxGet"]>(
    { query: taxGetByCategory, variables: { categoryId } }
  ).valueChanges.pipe(map(({ data }: { data: any }) => {
    console.log("returned Data");
    return data.taxGet;
  }));
}
```

**HTML**

```
<dxi-item itemType="group">
            <dxi-item   [label]="{ text: '  Category ' }"
            dataField="categoryId"
            alignment="right"
            editorType="dxSelectBox" 
            [editorOptions]="{
                items: category,
                placeholder: 'Select Category ',
                displayExpr: 'categoryName',
                valueExpr: 'id',
                showClearButton: 'true',
                onValueChanged: categoryChanged
                 }">
              </dxi-item>
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: @ritaj
Cannot read property 'getTaxByCategory' of undefined.

Comment: @AqibHafeez Show the all TS related code specially related to `taxService`

Comment: @AqibHafeez Show the TS Code where you have declared/ inject a `taxService`

Comment: I am injecting taxService in my constructor

Comment: @AqibHafeez Because the problem is your `taxService` is `undefined` -> so it could be you have missed `@Injectable()` decorator or wrong injection in the component

Comment: Show the full service code! and Constructor from component

Comment: But this method is working fine in ngOnInit(), I am getting undefined error when I call this in my event handler

Comment: @AqibHafeez can you add the exact error you are getting to your question?

Comment: @AqibHafeez `But this method is working fine in ngOnInit(), I am getting an undefined error when I call this in my event handler` --> Good! Now post the code which will be useful to reproduce an issue like HTML control for who's you have bound the event

Comment: @AqibHafeez and please also add the relevant code in question not in comment sections.

Comment: @AqibHafeez Is `dxi-item` this a custom control? Component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when passing the `onValueChanged: categoryChanged` the `categoryChanged` has its own reference to `this` (`this` is no longer the component). Change the `categoryChanged` to arrow function to make this work.

Arrow functions preserve the reference of `this` when they're passed further.

```
categoryChanged = (event: any) => {
  //console.log(event.previousValue);
  this.categoryId = event.value;
  this.taxService.getTaxByCategory(this.categoryId).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
  })
}
```

You can find more info about that in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696686/what-is-lexical-this)