# How arrow functions differ in JS Classes vs Normal objects

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions

Why does calling `click()` here prints out the `value` property.

```
class Button {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  click = () => {
    return this.value;
  }
}

let button = new Button("hi")
console.log(button.click()) //hi
```

And calling `click` here prints the value property.

```
function Button2(value){
  this.value = value

  this.click =  () => {
   return this.value
  }

}

let button2 = new Button2("hi")
console.log(button2.click()) //hi
```

However, calling `click()` here prints undefined. This is what I would expect to happen for both examples, since arrow functions have no `this`.

```
let button2 = {
    value:"hi",
    click: () => { return this.value }
}

console.log(button2.click()) //undefined
```

When printing all 3 objects in devtools, they look identical.

button, button2, and button3 when logged in devtools:

```
   {value: "hi", click: ƒ}
            click: () => { return this.value }
            value: "hi"
            __proto__: Object
```

Why does the first 2 examples print `hi` but the third prints `undefined`, even though the objects look the same when printed?

Comment: The invocation is only relevant for non-arrow functions

Comment: Also, as far as "arrow functions do not have a this", open your browser developer tools, go to the console, and type simply: `this`.  It will most likely report the window object.  So, *everything* has a this.  Edit: and in fact for some fun: `window.value = "weee"; var x = { test: () => this.value }; console.log(x.test());`

Comment: @Taplar Do you know why the class example provides different results?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback  Essentialy, yes

Comment: It's less of a 'class' thing, as it is a function thing.  Functions change what the context is, by their very nature.  When you call a pure function, their `this` is set to whatever they are called off of.

Comment: `window.value = "weee"; function test() { return this.value; }; var x = { value: 'my value', test }; console.log(x.test());` <= modified fun.  Now instead of an arrow function, we call an actual pure function.  And we call the pure function off of an object, so that object will be set as the `this`

Comment: And "classes", within the constructs of javascript, are essentially just functions.  The whole `class` definition syntax is just syntatical sugar around making those funcitons.

Comment: @Taplar I'm still kind of confused why the results are different. Both functions are called in the format object.click()

Comment: Because, remember, arrow functions **do not** change what `this` is.  It doesn't matter what you call them off of, or if you invoke them anonmyously, they leave `this` alone.

Comment: @Taplar So what is different about the 2 examples I showed? The objects look exactly the same (`button` and `button2`) and they are called in the same way (`button.click()` and `button2.click()`) but one prints the value and the other prints undefined.

Comment: Because remember, classes are essentially just functions in javascript.  So if you are operating off of a class instance, you are operating off of a function, and that function will have already altered what `this` is, within the chain of execution

Comment: Most of the discussion here doesn't have anything to do with the actual underlying reason for the difference in Behavior. A property initializer in a class body is executed in the context of the class Constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the primary concerns of arrow functions is that they inherit the `this` keyword from the lexical scope they are defined in. Inside your class, `this` refers to the class instance as you would expect, but in your object declaration, `this` will refer to the global object `window`.

@trincot makes a good point that the primary distinction is that one of these is **callable** and one is not - basically, the `class` is a function (and you can actually verify this with `typeof TestClass === 'function'`) which will form the lexical scope of the arrow method definition, but the object's lexical scope is just the global scope, so `this === globalThis === window`.

You can read the **[Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this)** for more information, and this is basically why it heavily recommends against arrow functions for method definitions. (Especially worth noting is that `.bind` and `.apply` do not work for arrow functions either, and the `this` parameter will be ignored.)

```js
class TestClass {
  // test defined inside TestClass instance scope
  // returns false
  test = () => console.log(this === window)
}

TestObject = {
  // object defined in global lexical scope
  // returns true
  test: () => console.log(this === globalThis && this === window)
};

new TestClass().test();
TestObject.test();
```

Comment: Just an opinion, but I rather think think `function`s are hacky. They have dynamic `this` binding so they could double as methods. If JS had manifest methods from the get go, `function` would have the arrow function behavior.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Ooo, I've never heard of "manifest methods," what are those? Google not producing meaningful results.

Comment: @Christian it was added in ES2015. Ex1: `const o = { m() { return this.x; } }`. Ex2: `class O { m() {return this.x;} }`. I should have said "manifest syntax for methods". I agree with you, he's doing great!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in the first code block, `click` is a [public field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields). The documentation on MDN specifies:

> When initializing fields, `this` refers to the class constructor.

By consequence, if that initialisation is an arrow function, then the lexical `this` at the time of execution of that function will be the same `this`. And it is a given that the `this` value of the class constructor is the *instance*.

This principle is further clarified when we represent that first code block without using `class` syntax:

```
function Button(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.click = () => {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

All `this` in this code are the *same* `this` (a consequence of ["lexical this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696686/what-is-lexical-this)).

The **second** code block has a plain old object property `click`. An object does not define `this` for the arrow functions that may be defined for its properties. Only functions (`function`, possibly constructors) define `this` by the way they are called. Your object is not called (it is not callable), and the *way* you call an arrow function has no influence on `this` either. So the `this` that occurs within the arrow function here, is determined by the larger context, which could be a wrapping function (not represented in your example), and how it is called. Or, by absence of such a context, `this` is the global object (or in strict mode: `undefined`).