# How lambda function parameter is passed to function body

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to javacscript and typescript, I found some code online, I do not understand it, can you explain it.

Thanks

original code
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retrywhen

```
export const genericRetryStrategy = ({
  maxRetryAttempts = 3,
  scalingDuration = 1000,
  excludedStatusCodes = []
}: {
  maxRetryAttempts?: number,
  scalingDuration?: number,
  excludedStatusCodes?: number[]
} = {}) => (attempts: Observable<any>) => {
  return attempts.pipe(
    mergeMap((error, i) => {
      const retryAttempt = i + 1;
      // if maximum number of retries have been met
      // or response is a status code we don't wish to retry, throw error
      if (
        retryAttempt > maxRetryAttempts ||
        excludedStatusCodes.find(e => e === error.status)
      ) {
        return throwError(error);
      }
      console.log(
        `Attempt ${retryAttempt}: retrying in ${retryAttempt *
          scalingDuration}ms`
      );
      // retry after 1s, 2s, etc...
      return timer(retryAttempt * scalingDuration);
    }),
    finalize(() => console.log('We are done!'))
  );
};
```

First question, how does this piece of code work

```
export const genericRetryStrategy = ({
  maxRetryAttempts = 3,
  scalingDuration = 1000,
  excludedStatusCodes = []
}: {
  maxRetryAttempts?: number,
  scalingDuration?: number,
  excludedStatusCodes?: number[]
} = {})
```

second question, there is `**=> (attempts: Observable<any>)** =>` between code above and function body, how `**maxRetryAttempts**` is pass to function body.

Comment: what part of it don't you understand? Be a little more clearer so we can help better.

Comment: Maybe this could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696686/what-is-lexical-this

Answer (score 1):

```
export const genericRetryStrategy = ({
  maxRetryAttempts = 3,
  scalingDuration = 1000,
  excludedStatusCodes = []
}: {
  maxRetryAttempts?: number,
  scalingDuration?: number,
  excludedStatusCodes?: number[]
} = {})
```

This declare a function that takes one argument. That part after the `:` on line 5 types that object as an object with three properties, each of which might be `undefined` or omitted (thats what the `?` means).

In lines 2-4 we see that this object is descructured, so that each property becomes a local variable. In addition, each variable has a default value (the `= 3` after the variable name) in case that property has no value on the argument object.

The last line provides a default value for the whole object, meaning you can omit it completely.

---

Now for this line:

```
//...
} = {}) => (attempts: Observable<any>) => {
```

In short, this function returns a function.

A simpler example:

you could write this:

```
const a = (x: number) => {
  return (y: number) => x * y
}
const b = a(2)
b(3) // 6
```

```
const a = (x: number) => (y: number) => x * y
const b = a(2)
b(3) // 6
```

In plain english, `a` is a function which, returns a function, which returns a value.

In the case of the code in your question `genericRetryStrategy` takes an objects that configures how the operation will retry and returns a function. That function that takes an observable to operate on, which reties according how you first called `genericRetryStrategy`

---

So to sum up:

```
export const genericRetryStrategy = ({
  maxRetryAttempts = 3,
  scalingDuration = 1000,
  excludedStatusCodes = []
}: {
  maxRetryAttempts?: number,
  scalingDuration?: number,
  excludedStatusCodes?: number[]
} = {}) => (attempts: Observable<any>) => {
  //..
}
```

is called like this:

```
const strategy = genericRetryStrategy({ maxRetryAttempts: 10 })
const doWithRetries = strategy(myObservable)
```