# What's the difference between anonymous function and => notation in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I just wanted to read a file with node.js.

I used to use this notation:

```
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

[Node.js’s documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) provides the following code:

```
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Arrow functions are new in ES6, so [they aren't supported in older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions).
- Arrow functions have lexical `this`.

  ```
  this.foo = 'bar';

  baz(function() {
      this.foo // probably undefined
  });

  baz(() => {
      this.foo // == 'bar'
  });
  ```

Comment: …and [more](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32535110/1048572)

Comment: josh and the other ones answered my question more clearly. My question is a bit more specific about the difference of those two notations. If I would only know what a arrow function (a phrase I just learned from these answers here) is I wouldn't know that there is no (practical) difference (for me).

Comment: yeah, if you don't need `this` for a method or `arguments.callee` (or `fn.name`) to do recursion, they are interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

=> is [es6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) notation. Arrow functions are ALWAYS anonymous. The two pieces of code you gave will function the same.

Answer (score -4):

The second is ECMA 6, the first is a bit older. There's no difference.