# What is the difference between assigning an arrow function to a variable and creating a named function in ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, ecmascript-6

What is the difference between assigning an anonymous `arrow function` to a variable (here constant):

```
const consumeError = (error)=> {
    console.error(`Aborted, reason: ${error}`);
};
```

And creating a `named function`:

```
function consumeError2(error) {
    console.error(`Aborted, reason: ${error}`);
}
```

I am don't see any difference in behavior. Are there any hidden implications regarding performance, memory leaks, coding style and so on?

Comment: lambdas don't have an (own) `this`- or `arguments`-object.

Comment: @Thomas, you mean "arrow functions" not "lambdas". `function(x) { return x; }` is also a "lambda" and it does have its own `this` and `arguments`.

Comment: Just looked it up, you're right. _I had learned that "lambda" is synonymous to "arrow function", but it actually refers to "anonymous function". You live and learn; thx @naomik_

Comment: I think the explanation **"don't have its own `this`"** is misleading. Arrows bind their `this` lexically instead of dynamically. Hence they have a `this` but it depends on the environment in which they were defined.

Comment: @Iven: Actually that they "don't have an own `this`" is technically more correct - [it's not bound to anything](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32539428/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi I see, `this` is inherited from the lexical environment, thanks!