# Converting ECMAScript 6's arrow function to a regular function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have the following arrow function

`if( rowCheckStatuses.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) ){}`

`rowCheckStatuses` is an array of 1's and 0's, this arrow function adds them all up to produce a number. This number acts as a boolean to determine whether or not there is at least one "1" in the array.

The issue is, I don't really understand how arrow functions work, and my IDE thinks it's bad syntax and refuses to check the rest of my document for syntax errors.

How would I go about converting this to a regular function to alleviate both issues?

Comment: `function(a, b) { return a+b; }`

Comment: Obviously not a duplicate. OP asks about converting => to regular functions.

Comment: @le_m Which would be trivial if they understood them.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can refactor it as:

```
if( rowCheckStatuses.reduce(function(a, b){return a + b}, 0)
```

The initial accumulator isn't necessary (unless you expect the array to be empty sometimes), it could be:

```
if( rowCheckStatuses.reduce(function(a, b){return a + b})
```

> This number acts as a boolean to determine whether or not there is at least one "1" in the array

It might be faster (and clearer) to use:

```
if( rowCheckStatuses.some(function(a){return a == 1}))
```

which will return *true* if there are any 1s in *rowCheckStatuses* and will return as soon as one is encountered. Another alternative is *indexOf*:

```
if( rowCheckStatuses.indexOf(1) != -1)
```

Lots of alternatives.

Comment: This isn't technically exactly equivalent. You lose the lexical `this` if you change from an arrow function to a function expression. In this case, it doesn't matter because the function doesn't reference this. But it's a good point to keep in mind.

The good news is it's easy - just add a `.bind(this)` to the function.

Comment: @JoeAttardi—good point, but as you say, lexical *this* isn't relevant in this case. ;-)

Answer (score 13):

An arrow function can usually be converted by replacing

```
(<args>) => <body>
```

with

```
function(<args>) { return <body>; }
```

So yours would be

```
rowCheckStatuses.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0)
```

---

There are exceptions to this rule so it's important that you read up on [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) if you want to know all of the differences. You should also note that arrow functions have a lexical `this`.

Answer (score 5):

Replacing arrow functions with regular functions is **usually** unproblematic:

```
var f = x => y;
var g = function(x) { return y; }
```

Or, in your specific example:

```
rowCheckStatuses.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
rowCheckStatuses.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
```

However, be aware of the **exceptions**:

Arrow functions don't bind a `this` value. Accessing `this` in an arrow function might thus return the value of the enclosing execution context's `this`:

```js
function MyClass() {}
MyClass.prototype.f = () => this;
MyClass.prototype.g = function() { return this; }

myClass = new MyClass();
console.log(myClass.f()); // logs `Window`
console.log(myClass.g()); // logs `myClass`
```

Arrow functions also don't have access to a local `arguments` object. Accessing `arguments` in an arrow function might e. g. return the `arguments` of an enclosing function:

```js
function test() {

  var f = () => arguments;
  var g = function() { return arguments; }
  
  console.log(f()); // logs test's arguments
  console.log(g()); // logs g's arguments
}

test('x');
```

The same holds for `new.target` and `super`. See also [What are the differences (if any) between ES6 arrow functions and functions bound with Function.prototype.bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535110/what-are-the-differences-if-any-between-es6-arrow-functions-and-functions-boun)