# Javascript - To remove duplicates in array object for ES5

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have the an array, `listPeople` and to eliminate duplicates I use the following code in ES6:

```js
var listPeople = [{
    "nomCustomer": "Fran",
    "attrName": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "nomCustomer": "John",
    "attrName": "ccc"
  },
  {
    "nomCustomer": "Paul",
    "attrName": "ddd"
  },
  {
    "nomCustomer": "Paul",
    "attrName": "ddd"
  }
];

var list = listPeople.reduce((unique, o) => {
  if (!unique.some(obj => obj.nomCustomer === o.nomCustomer && obj.attrName === o.attrName)) {
    unique.push(o);
  }
  return unique;
}, []);

console.log(list)
```

What would it be like for ES5?

Comment: the same without without the arrow function ...?

Comment: ES5 includes `.reduce()`

Comment: Have you checked babel https://babeljs.io/en/repl ? I guess instead of asking you could have convert it online.

Comment: What's the harm in leaving this open for answers?

Comment: @Ben what's the benefit? We already have a canonical for getting uniques from array. Moreover, the code here works and translating it to ES5 is trivial. [It also has duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668185/converting-ecmascript-6s-arrow-function-to-a-regular-function). Any reason another copy of existing answers is needed?

Comment: We can both link to the canonical answer and supply a specific answer for this particular flavour of the question. I don't see a conflict there. The benefit is that it delivers a more positive overall outcome. The questioner gets what they want and contributors get the chance to help.

Comment: @Ben I personally see no value in just posting re-posting the same content in different places. That's why we have dupes. Feel free to run it by [meta] to verify, though.

Comment: It's not the same content. It is related content. Maybe tightly so. But different content.

Comment: `_.uniqBy(listPeople, e => e.nomCustomer && e.attrName)` https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy
Do not underestimate the power of lodash. With tools like webpack and the ability to perform tree shaking, bringing lodash into your project will save you so much time at little to no cost relative to the time savings