# Readability for class method as callback: with .bind or wrap in an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Lets say I want to assign a class method as a callback, which is better? By better, I really mean for style & readability.

```
const Foo = class {
  /** @param {!Promise} */
  optionOne(theirPromise) {
    theirPromise(this.myHandler_.bind(this));
  }
  /** @param {!Promise} */
  optionTwo(theirPromise) {
    theirPromise(() => this.myHandler_());
  }
  /** @private */
  myHandler_() {
    // Do something classy
  }
};
```

I read the arrow function call as cleaner in this case, but if there are a bunch of parameters in the callback, it starts to get silly:

```
addCallback((a, b, c, d, e, f) => this.myHandler_(a, b, c, d, e, f))
```

I see the penalty of wrapping in a function, memory mostly, assuming the compiler doesn't trim the call away.

Comment: "memory mostly" --- `.bind` also creates a function.

Comment: That trailing underscore is weird. If you want to focus on readability/conventions, go for `_myHandler` :-)

Comment: @zerkms the arrow function forms a closure that is more complicated to handle for the compiler, so there could be implementation differences. I'm not going to guess which is better though.

Comment: @zerkms Didn't know `.bind` creates a function. Neat.

@Bergi Trailing underscore for private methods is in the Google JS Style Guide: https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#naming-method-names

Answer (score 4):

Style and readability are subjective.

The arrow function could be considered a better practice since the parameters and arguments are explicit (more important if the method declaration is far away). `bind` could be considered more maintainable, as you don't need to touch it when adding/removing parameters. However, you can achieve the same with an arrow function and rest/spread syntax:

```
theirPromise((...args) => this.myHandler_(...args));
```

Now the only difference is `bind` being shorter, creating a function with correct `.length`, evaluating the `this.myHandler_`/`this` references immediately and [some other peanuts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32539428/1048572).

Comment: It's also important to note that `bind` effectively creates a copy of the function with its new scope — this can be good to use if you plan on reusing that function more than once

Comment: @NickZuber "with its new scope" --- what does it mean?

Comment: @zerkms I was referring to the scope that was just bound to the function

Comment: @NickZuber It's called "context" or "receiver", and that's not a difference because you could share/reuse the arrow function just as well.

Comment: @Bergi How would you be able to "reuse" an arrow function in this way? With binding, you can have `let newFun = oldFun.bind(this)` and then use `newFun` where ever you need, whereas with an arrow function you only bind the scope _as_ you execute the function — how can you "reuse that"?

Comment: @NickZuber `let newFun = () => oldFun.call(this); newFun(); newFun();` works just as well. Not sure what you mean by "*bind the scope as you execute the function*" - the closure over a scope is formed when the function is created, not when it's executed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like the spread operator use.

I should have mentioned that a subjective answer was what I was expecting / looking for, or some kind of convention or style guide reference.

Comment: @cyrus I don't know of any that detail this particular thing. In cases where the differences don't matter, I believe it comes down to the "*oh let's go for new shiny ES6 style everywhere*" vs "*let's keep it simple and stay with ES5 where easily possible*" fractions. Oh, and consistency is a big thing, so if you need arrow functions for some method callbacks you'll want to use them everywhere.