# Understanding double return function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to understand the double return function in Javascript

I went through the other questions which was asked in SF regarding the return statement but I wasn't able to make sense out of it.

So, I was trying to understand HOC in react when I stumbled upon an article on medium.

The author wrote this line of code in his example.

```
const yell = (PassedComponent) =>
  ({ children, ...props }) =>
    <PassedComponent {...props}>
      {children.toUpperCase()}!
    </PassedComponent>

const Title = (props) => <h1>{props.children}</h1>

const AngryTitle = yell(Title)

<AngryTitle>Whatever</AngryTitle>

//=> <h1>WHATEVER!</h1>
```

Our HOC (Yell) here can also be return as

```
const yell = PassedComponent => ({children, ...props}) => {
    return (
```

Since there is two arrow function and something like this after first arrow function `({children, ...props})`, I think it is double return HOC function.

[Question]: **Can someone explain me double return or the code above?.**

Comment: That's not really a double return. It's a function that returns another function. This would be **similar** [(_not exactly equivalent_)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535110/what-are-the-differences-if-any-between-es6-arrow-functions-and-functions-boun) to `function yell(...){ return function(...){ return ...; } }`

Comment: @blex either way, can you please explain the above question in details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to make things clearer, let's use the full syntax, by using curly braces and `return` statements:

```
const yell = (PassedComponent) => {
    return ({ children, ...props }) => {
        return (
            <PassedComponent {...props}>
                {children.toUpperCase()}!
            </PassedComponent>
        );
    };
}
```

Yes, the `return` word is used twice. But there are two functions here. And each one only has one `return` statement.

The outer one takes a component as parameter, and it returns a function. That function is now a component *(yes, components are functions)* that can be instanciated with children and props.

Answer (score 0):

```
const foo = arg1 => arg2 => arg1 + ar2;
```

Is a function that returns another function and is the same as:

```
function foo(arg1){
   return function(arg2){
     return arg1 + arg2
   }    
}
```

To get the inner return value you need to do

```
foo(input1)(input2)
```

Or variation where you store the returned function with an initial input  and use it again

```
var f1 = foo(input1)
console.log(f1(input2))
console.log(f1(input3))
```