# What is the typescript syntax for combining ES6 generators with fat arrow syntax?

Tags: typescript, generator

I am trying to use ES6 generators in combination with the fat arrow syntax.
But i am unable to find any example.

```js
class PingPong{
 ping= *(val)=>{
  yield "hello"+val;
 }
}
var a=new PingPong();
a.ping(0);
```

I know that i need to use the '*' but tsc does not seem to accept it.

Comment: Maybe not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661306/can-i-use-es6s-arrow-function-syntax-with-generators-fat-arrow-notation?rq=1

Comment: In typescript you should use `async / await` syntax which transpiles to es6 function generators.