# Can I use generator-function with arrow function?

Tags: javascript, generator, arrow-functions

I wander if it's possible to use arrow function with generators like this:

```
app.use( *() => {
    ...body of function
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try running it ?

Comment: Ok, you're ironic... and how should syntax looks like?

Comment: Yes I am, you're basically asking if you can run the code you wrote, go ahead, try it yourself and see what happens ! Then, when you'll see it doesn't work, either do your own searches, or look at @hsz 's answer.

Comment: If needed, you can easily omit generator function name to achieve anonymous function, like `app.use(function*() { /* body of generator */  })`. 
More discuss here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34108006/7878274

Comment: Yes, but for arrows function maybe works like `*() => {}" or "()* => {}` and so on.. You see? It's difference to be smart and think you're smart...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to make it shorter than described in the documentation:

```
function* name([param[, param[, ... param]]]) {
   statements
}
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

Answer (score 0):

You can, but not really in a nice way. It's not shorter and does not look that pretty. Check this out:

```js
function* iterable(arg) {
    yield* [];
}

async function* asyncIterable(arg) {
    yield* [];
}

const arrowIterable = arg => {
    return {
        *[Symbol.iterator]() {
            yield* [];
        },
    };
};

const arrowAsyncIterable = arg => {
    return {
        async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
            yield* [];
        },
    };
};
```

This works because an iterable is basically an object with the `Symbol.iterator` or `Symbol.asyncIterator` set to an iterator. A generator is an iterator!

Enjoy!