# JSON.net parent key

Tags: c#, json, json.net, key-value

I'm having a hard time getting the parent key/property/attribute of my JSON objects using JSON.net. That is, I want the *outermost* property name, as a string, without knowing beforehand/visually what it is. I'm currently iterating over a set of KeyValuePair items and attempting to, for each of those, log out the parent from something that looks like

```
{"parentKey": 
 {
  "Name": "Name",
  "Id": "123",
  "Other": null,
  "nestedArr": 
   [
    "idx0", 
    "idx1",
    "idx2"
   ]
 }
}
```

I've tried both `keyValue.Value.Ancestors()` and `keyValue.Value.Parent`. With the former, I'm getting what looks to be the function definition... I'm actually not sure what it is: `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken+<GetAncestors>d_ _ 42`. Completely beffuddled by that, because based on the usage examples I've scrounged up here, I'm using it to standard.

With the latter, I log out the entire object, or else what appears to be the entire preceding KeyValuePair, rather than just the string "parentKey", which is what I want. The JSON.net docs aren't the best as far as explicit usage examples and what to expect (or maybe it's just that being new to C#, I can't make sense of them), but in any case, I'm kind of unclear on why this is happening and how to accomplish what I want. This is what I'm trying:

```
foreach (var keyValue in jObjList[0])  //jObjList is a List<JObject> defined above
{
    Console.WriteLine(keyValue.Value.Ancestors());
    Console.WriteLine(keyValue.Value.Parent);
    if (keyValue.Value.GetType() == typeof(JObject))//same block goes for if it's typeof(JArray)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(keyValue.Key);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: in the JSON given, and within the loop defined above, for example, in order to get my parent keys (that's just what I'm calling them), my code simply says, `if (keyValue.Value.GetType() == typeof(JObject)`, write `keyValue.Key` to the console, and the same goes for if getType() is a JArray. In either case, `keyValue.Key` is a parent key, if that makes sense. What I mean to say by this is that it is a property that points to another Array or Object. My issue is that, as I'm doing this loop recursively, when I get down to a nested Array or Object, my code has no way of realizing that, although there is a new "parent key" currently, like with `nestedArr`, for example, the parent key of nestedArr is still "parentKey".

the code is abridged, but that's the idea.

All clarifications and corrections are welcome and appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You are seeing `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken+<GetAncestors>d_ _ 42` for `Console.WriteLine(keyValue.Value.Ancestors())` because [`Ancestors`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs) is an [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) whose evaluation is [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756958/how-yield-implements-the-pattern-of-lazy-loading), rather than an explicit collection.  What you are seeing is the `ToString()` output of the not-yet-evaluated enumerable.

If what you want to do is to climb up the parent list of a given `JToken` and find the lowest parent that has a `"parentKey"` property, then get the value of that `parentKey`, then this is how you would do it:

```
    JToken token = keyValue.Value; // Here I'm declaring JToken explicitly for clarity.  Normally I would use var token = ...

    var parentKey = token.AncestorsAndSelf()     // Climb up the json container parent/child hierachy
        .Select(p => p.SelectToken("parentKey")) // Get the "parentKey" property in the current parent (if present)
        .FirstOrDefault(k => k != null);         // Return the first one found.

    Console.WriteLine(parentKey);
```

**Update**

To get the name of the JSON property *highest* in the JSON container hierarchy, you would do:

```
    var name = token.AncestorsAndSelf() // Walk up the list of ancestors
        .OfType<JProperty>()            // For each that is a property
        .Select(p => p.Name)            // Select the name
        .LastOrDefault();               // And return the last (topmost).
```

**Update 2**

If you're looking for the *first* property name that appears in a JSON file, you can do the following, using [`JContainer.DescendantsAndSelf()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_DescendantsAndSelf.htm):

```
    var json = @"[{""parentKey"": 
     {
      ""Name"": ""Name"",
      ""Id"": ""123"",
      ""Other"": null,
      ""nestedArr"": 
       [
        ""idx0"", 
        ""idx1"",
        ""idx2""
       ]
     }
    }]";

    var root = (JContainer)JToken.Parse(json);
    var name = root.DescendantsAndSelf() // Loop through tokens in or under the root container, in document order. 
        .OfType<JProperty>()             // For those which are properties
        .Select(p => p.Name)             // Select the name
        .FirstOrDefault();               // And take the first.

    Debug.WriteLine(name); // Prints "parentKey"
```

([`JContainer`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer.htm) represents a JSON node that can contain child nodes, such as an object or array.)

Comment: i don't really understand how the lambdas are working in your example. could you maybe comment on what's going on there? also, I need a way to access "parentKey" kind of anonymously, if you will. I don't know what "parentKey" will be, so I can't pass it as a parameter. I just need to know in a dynamic fashion what the outermost property of a keyValuePair is. I'll edit my Q for clarity.

Comment: @spb - If you can edit your question to include a complete example of your JSON and what you what to print to the console, I can probably explain more clearly.

Comment: thanks for commenting out the code. :) really helpful. hopefully my edits shed some light on what i'm trying to accomplish/what i'm working with

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102279/discussion-between-spb-and-dbc).